# How can I delete a remote tag?

Tags: git, git-tag

How can I delete a Git tag that has already been pushed?

Answer (score 7853, accepted):

You can push an 'empty' reference to the remote tag name:

```
git push origin :tagname
```

Or, more expressively, use the `--delete` option (or `-d` if your git version is older than 1.8.0):

```
git push --delete origin tagname
```

Note that git has tag namespace and branch namespace so you may use the same name for a branch and for a tag. If you want to make sure that you cannot accidentally remove the branch instead of the tag, you can specify full ref which will never delete a branch:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/tagname
```

If you also need to delete the local tag, use:

```
git tag --delete tagname
```

---

#### Background

Pushing a branch, tag, or other ref to a remote repository involves specifying "which repo, what source, what destination?"

```
git push remote-repo source-ref:destination-ref
```

A real world example where you push your master branch to the origin's master branch is:

```
git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

Which because of default paths, can be shortened to:

```
git push origin master:master
```

Tags work the same way:

```
git push origin refs/tags/release-1.0:refs/tags/release-1.0
```

Which can also be shortened to:

```
git push origin release-1.0:release-1.0
```

By omitting the source ref (the part before the colon), you push 'nothing' to the destination, deleting the ref on the remote end.

Comment: +1 for both answering the question and explaining the general case, and detailing the unabridged syntax's meaning

Comment: And just in case someone wonders how to delete multiple tags at a time you simple list them using white space, e.g. `git push --delete origin tag1 tag2`. Same is valid for local tags deletion `git tag -d tag1 tag2`

Comment: If tag name collides with a branch name you may end up with deleting your branch. Ha-ha. See the second answer - it's more ecological

Comment: The background helped me a lot to understand when i got an error: `error: dst refspec "my-tag" matches more than one.
error: failed to push some refs` that I could execute `git push origin :refs/tags/my-tag` to specifically delete only the tag, and not the branch.

Comment: It is also interesting to know that `git tag -d \`git tag\`` will delete all local tags. Same applies for `git push --delete origin \`git tag\`` assuming you pulled the remote tags locally. That was handy in a test environment.

Comment: Apparently (at least in GitLab) changing (and thus deleting) tags is a capability disjoint from that of creating a tag: `remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to change existing tags on this project.` (in response to trying to remove a tag that I erroneously created).

Comment: The fact we're at 6700+ upvotes and that it is this freaking complicated probably means it could be redesigned.

Comment: perfect answer, thank you.

once I deleted the remote tags, the simplest way to sync locally without running again all tagnames is to prune: `git fetch --prune --prune-tags`

Comment: I absolutely hate that deleting a remote tag does not contain the word "tag", give me anxiety every time I use it

Answer (score 610):

A more straightforward way is

```
git push --delete origin YOUR_TAG_NAME
```

IMO prefixing colon syntax is a little bit odd in this situation

Comment: I think this is the proper way... other syntax look more like hacks to me.

Comment: This works. One addition: If you have a branch and a tag with the same name, you can put the word `tag` before your tag name to make sure you get the tag, not the branch.

Comment: @andypaxo What the command takes is refspecs, the correct way would be prefixing the tags with `refs/tags/`, like this: `refs/tags/v2.3.1`.

Comment: I had 'bad' tag name created on remote server somehow, which had special characters, so I can't sync with that, so simply removed that with your suggestion:   git push --delete origin "service--<default>--151"        , can't remove it not with intellij, not with stash, not with sourceTree. Thanks !

Comment: For those reading this long after the answer was posted, at the time, the (now accepted) answer did not have this content in it; later on this answer's content was (very narrowly) suggested edit'd in to the accepted one. This is one of those weird edge cases where Stack Overflow's "the best answer rises to the top system" kinda fails, on one hand I'm happy the accepted answer has the right information because most readers won't look past the top answer, but I'm not thrilled as to how we got here... I hope future readers will not think this answer is just a copy/paste.

Answer (score 280):

If you have a remote tag `v0.1.0` to delete, and your remote is `origin`, then simply:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/v0.1.0
```

If you also need to delete the tag locally:

```
git tag -d v0.1.0
```

See [**Adam Franco**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5480292/535871) for an explanation of Git's unusual `:` syntax for deletion.

Comment: this also works with jgit. the :tag shorthand does not work with jgit

Comment: I got `fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in :/refs/tags/0.0.1`
...?

Comment: @ChaimEliyah you have a leading slash, maybe that's your problem

Comment: Better answer, as this also works if you have a branch and a tag that's called the same.

Comment: Just `:tagname` should work for the remote deletion.

Comment: best answer. explaining that actually you push the same tag that you want to delete, and not for example the previous one

Answer (score 128):

**Delete all local tags and get the list of remote tags**:

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
git fetch
```

**Remove all remote tags**

```
git tag -l | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

**Clean up local tags**

```
git tag -l | xargs git tag -d
```

Comment: How to remove all tags from the local and remote repos. This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: git fetch, delete remote and then clean up locals, worked beautifully!

Comment: slow, but the most straightforward

Comment: but,when the other one exec git-push, all the deleted tags will be reserved

Answer (score 87):

`git push --delete origin $TAGNAME` is the correct approach (in addition of a local delete).

But: make sure to use Git 2.31+ (Q1 2021).

"[`git push $there --delete`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/140045821aa78da3a80a7d7c8f707b955e1ab40d/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> should have been diagnosed as an error, but instead turned into a matching push, which has been corrected with Git 2.31 (Q1 2021).

See [commit 20e4164](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20e416409fc2bc260faf65a0fc74927ed0d3ca12) (23 Feb 2021) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1400458](https://github.com/git/git/commit/140045821aa78da3a80a7d7c8f707b955e1ab40d), 25 Feb 2021)</sup>

> ### [`push`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20e416409fc2bc260faf65a0fc74927ed0d3ca12): do not turn `--delete ''` into a matching push
>
> <sup>Noticed-by: Tilman Vogel</sup>

> When we added a syntax sugar "[`git push remote --delete`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/20e416409fc2bc260faf65a0fc74927ed0d3ca12/Documentation/git-push.txt#L182)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---delete))</sup> `<ref>` to "[`git push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/20e416409fc2bc260faf65a0fc74927ed0d3ca12/Documentation/git-push.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push))</sup> as a synonym to the canonical [`git push remote`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/20e416409fc2bc260faf65a0fc74927ed0d3ca12/Documentation/git-push.txt#L453)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-remoterejected))</sup> : syntax at [f517f1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f517f1f2e9c9e3abe0fde1b3c9a7bb20fdb5ba55) ("`builtin-push`: [`add`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f517f1f2e9c9e3abe0fde1b3c9a7bb20fdb5ba55/Documentation/git-add.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add))</sup> `--delete` as syntactic sugar for :foo", 2009-12-30, Git v1.7.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/84d52cabe7044786b5cc448ffeb97b7c1e667156)), we weren't careful enough to make sure that `<ref>` is not empty.
>
> Blindly rewriting "`--delete <ref>`" to "`:<ref>`" means that an empty string `<ref>` results in refspec "`:`", which is the syntax to ask for "matching" push that does not delete anything.
>
> Worse yet, if there were matching refs that can be fast-forwarded, they would have been published prematurely, even if the user feels that they are not ready yet to be pushed out, which would be a real disaster.

Comment: it works! damn, why they don't put this option on github in releases. I was doing an update of the same tag with elder zips. it took me a while to notice date was not ok. and then I did several tries, until I saw this page.

Answer (score 79):

From your terminal, do this:

```
git fetch
git tag
git tag -d {tag-name}
git push origin :refs/tags/{tag-name}
```

Now go to Github.com and refresh, they disappear.

Answer (score 68):

```
git tag -d your_tag_name
git push origin :refs/tags/your_tag_name
```

The first line deletes `your_tag_name` from **local** repo and second line deletes `your_tag_name` from **remote** repo.

For those who use GitHub, one more step is needed: **discarding draft**.
[image]

Answer (score 52):

This two steps works fine:

```
# delete local tag '1.0.0'
git tag -d 1.0.0

# delete remote tag '1.0.0' (eg, GitHub version too)
git push origin :refs/tags/1.0.0
```

Answer (score 46):

To remove the tag from the remote repository:

```
git push --delete origin TAGNAME
```

You may also want to delete the tag locally:

```
git tag -d TAGNAME
```

Comment: so one line to do both: ``git push --delete origin TAGNAME && git tag -d TAGNAME``

Answer (score 29):

### Delete a single tag:

```bash
# Local tag example:
git tag -d v1.0.0

# Remote tag example:
git push -d origin v1.0.0
```

### Delete multiple tags:

```bash
# Local tag example:
git tag -d v1.0.0 v1.1.0

# Remote tag example:
git push -d origin v1.0.0 v1.1.0
```

### Delete tags that match a particular pattern:

```bash
# Local tag example:
git tag -d $(git tag -l "*beta*")

# Remote tag example:
git push -d origin $(git tag -l "*beta*")
```

Answer (score 28):

#### Delete local tag '12345'

```
git tag -d 12345
```

#### Delete remote tag '12345' (eg; GitHub version too)

```
git push origin :refs/tags/12345
```

#### alternative approach

```
git push --delete origin tagName
git tag -d tagName
```

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Just notice that, if you have a remote branch named as a remote tag, these commands are ambiguous:

```
git push origin :tagname
git push --delete origin tagname
```

So you must use this command to delete the tag:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/<tag>
```

and this one to delete the branch:

```
git push origin :refs/heads/<branch>
```

If not, you would get an error like this:

```
error: dst refspec <tagname> matches more than one.
error: failed to push some refs to '<repo>'
```

Comment: Short and concise. This post along with MeganZhou's popped out as being the answer to why we were having issues, the branchname and tagname were identical. I deleted the local tag and pushed to :refs/tags and all was good.

Answer (score 13):

If you have created a tag called `release01` in a Git repository you would remove it from your repository by doing the following:

```
git tag -d release01 
git push origin :refs/tags/release01
```

To remove one from a Mercurial repository:

```
hg tag --remove featurefoo
```

Please reference https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=282175551

Answer (score 13):

### Up to 100x faster method for thousands of remote tags

After reading through these answers while needing to delete over 11,000 tags, I learned these methods relying or `xargs` take far too long, unless you have hours to burn.

Struggling, I found two *much* faster ways. For both, start with `git tag` or `git ls-remote --tags` to make a list of tags you want to delete on the remote. In the examples below you can omit or replace `sorting_proccessing_etc` with any `grep`ing, `sort`ing, `tail`ing or `head`ing you want (*e.g.* `grep -P "my_regex" | sort | head -n -200` *etc*) :

---

#### This first method is by far the fastest, maybe *20 to 100 times* faster than using `xargs`, and works with a least several *thousand* tags at a time.

```bsh
git push origin $(< git tag | sorting_processing_etc \
| sed -e 's/^/:/' | paste -sd " ") #note exclude "<" for zsh
```

How does this work?
The normal, line-separated list of tags is converted to a single line of space-separated tags, each prepended with `:` so . . .

```
tag1   becomes
tag2   ======>  :tag1 :tag2 :tag3
tag3
```

Using `git push` with this format tag pushes *nothing* into each remote ref, erasing it (the normal format for pushing this way is `local_ref_path:remote_ref_path`).

#### Method two is broken out as a separate answer [elsewhere on this same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46105020/657764)

---

After both of these methods, you'll probably want to delete your local tags too.
This is much faster so we can go back to using `xargs` and `git tag -d`, which is sufficient.

```bsh
git tag | sorting_processing_etc | xargs -L 1 git tag -d
```

OR similar to the remote delete:

```
git tag -d $(< git tag | sorting_processing_etc | paste -sd " ")
```

Comment: You should split this into a few different answers. The answer with multiple tags on one line is, without a doubt, the right answer for bulk tag deletion.

It's actually a little difficult to find this info nearly anywhere else. Even knowing what I'm looking for I have a hard time finding it in the git help page :)


So kudos to you and highlight that as the right answer, and move the GitHub API one to a different place.


And finally, the deleting tags locally, in bulk, works with space delimited tags (get rid of the colons)

Comment: Thanks for the praise and suggestions. I will split this up. I don't understand your comment about local tag deletion. I don't think my final command snippet uses any colons,  but I'm on mobile so maybe missing something.

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that what you're doing to delete remote tags, works with deleting local tags, providing the entire list at once. :)

Just instead of git push origin :tag1 :tag2 etc. you'd do git tag --delete tag1 tag2 tag3 that way you can have a total cleanup.

Again, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 13):

If you use SourceTree - a great Git GUI - then you can easily do this without the command line by doing the following:

1. Open your repository in SourceTree
2. Select and expand the "Tags" tab on the left
3. Right-Click on the tag you want deleted
4. Select "Delete YOUR_TAG_NAME"
5. In the verification window, select "Remove Tag From Remotes"

YOUR_TAG_NAME will now be removed from your local repository and all remotes - be it GitHub, BitBucket, or wherever else you listed as a remote for that repository.

Also, if you deleted a tag locally but not on the remote origins, and you want to delete it everywhere, then just create a new tag that has the same name and is attached at the same commit as the origins. Then, repeat the steps above to delete everywhere.

Comment: Note that *this is safe* and will not delete any commit - only the tag itself

Answer (score 9):

***Update 2023***

First, delete a tag from the local repository.
To delete a local Git tag, use the `git tag` command with the `-d` option.

```
git tag -d <tag_name>
```

For example, you would run if you wanted to delete a local tag named `v1.0` on your commit list.

```
git tag -d v1.0
```

If deleting is successful, you can see something like this output.

```
Deleted tag 'v1.0' (was 808b598)
```

List your existing tags using the tag command and the `-l` option to ensure that tags were correctly deleted.

```
git tag -l
```

Second, delete the tag from the remote repository.
To delete a remote Git tag, use the “git push” command with the “–delete” option and specify the tag name.

```
git push --delete origin <tag_name>
```

Back to the previous example, if you want to delete the remote Git tag named “v1.0”, you would run.

```
git push --delete origin v1.0
```

If deleting is successful, you can see something like this output.

```
To https://github.com/SCHKN/repo.git
 - [deleted]         v1.0
```

To delete a remote Git tag, use the `git push` command and specify the tag name using the `refs` syntax.

```
git push origin :refs/tags/<tag_name>
```

Back to the example, to delete a tag named `v1.0`, you would run.

```
git push origin :refs/tags/v1.0


To https://github.com/SCHKN/repo.git
 - [deleted]         v1.0
```

***Why should we specify the `refs/tags` instead of just specifying the tag name?***

Sometimes, your tag may have the same name as your branch.

If you tried to delete your Git tag without specifying the `refs/tags` you would get the following error.

```
git push origin :v1.0


error: dst refspec v1.0 matches more than one.
error: failed to push some refs to '<repository>'
```

Consequently, you need to specify that you are trying to delete a Git tag and not a Git repository.

Answer (score 8):

Simple script to remove given tag from both local and origin locations.
With a check if tag really exists.

```
if [ $(git tag -l "$1") ]; then
    git tag --delete  $1
    git push --delete origin $1

    echo done.
else
    echo tag named "$1" was not found
fi
```

How to use:

- Create shell script file (e.g. git-tag-purge.sh) and paste content.
- chmod your script file to make it executable.
- Make the script globally available
- cd to your git project
- Call script (e.g.

  ```
  $>git-tag-purge.sh tag_name
  ```

  )

Answer (score 8):

As @CubanX suggested, I've split this answer from my original:

#### Here is a method which is several times faster than `xargs` and may scale much more with tweaking. It uses the [Github API](http://developer.github.com/v3/git/refs/#delete-a-reference), a personal access token, and leverages the utility [`parallel`](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html).

```bsh
git tag | sorting_processing_etc | parallel --jobs 2 curl -i -X DELETE \ 
https://api.github.com/repos/My_Account/my_repo/git/refs/tags/{} -H 
\"authorization: token GIT_OAUTH_OR_PERSONAL_KEY_HERE\"  \
-H \"cache-control: no-cache\"`
```

[`parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) has many operating modes, but generally parallelizes any command you give it while allowing you to set limits on the number of processes. You can alter the `--jobs 2` parameter to allow faster operation, but I had problems with Github's [rate limits](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting), which are currently 5000/hr, but also seems to have an undocumented short-term limit as well.

---

After this, you'll probably want to delete your local tags too.
This is much faster so we can go back to using `xargs` and `git tag -d`, which is sufficient.

```bsh
git tag | sorting_processing_etc | xargs -L 1 git tag -d
```

Comment: This seems much more complicated than the accepted answe.  What is the benefit?

Comment: If you need to delete several thousand tags, then the speed is 10-100 times faster

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  The OP asked about deleting a single tag.  I couldnt imagine why someone would use this approach for a single tag.  Perhaps this answer is better for another question involving deleting many tags

Comment: I don't think it exists. I could create it to answer myself. Do you want to think that's appropriate?

Comment: I do!  I think it's a fairly common practice here, actually.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to remove all tags except for those that match a pattern so that I could delete all but the last couple of months of production tags, here's what I used to great success:

**Delete All Remote Tags & Exclude Expression From Delete**

```
git tag -l | grep -P '^(?!Production-2017-0[89])' | xargs -n 1 git push --delete origin
```

**Delete All Local Tags & Exclude Expression From Delete**

```
git tag -l | grep -P '^(?!Production-2017-0[89])' | xargs git tag -d
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're using PowerShell, and you want to delete a bunch of them:

```
# Local tags:
git tag -l | foreach { git tag -d $_ }

# Remote tags:
git tag -l | foreach { git push --delete origin $_ }
```

Of course, you can also filter them before deleting:

```
git tag -l | Where-Object { $_ -like "build-*" } | foreach { git tag -d $_ }
```

Answer (score 7):

For tortoise git users, at a scale of hundreds tags, you can delete multiple tags at once using UI, but the UI is well hidden under context menu.

From explorer windows right click -> Browse references -> Right click on ref/refmotes/name -> choose **'Delete remote tags'**

[image]

See https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-browse-ref.html

Answer (score 6):

The other answers point out how to accomplish this, but you should keep in mind the consequences since this is a remote repository.

The git tag man page, in the [On Retagging](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-tag.html#_on_re_tagging) section, has a good explanation of how to courteously inform the remote repo's other users of the change. They even give a handy announcement template for communicating how others should get your changes.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like a lot of work for something `xargs` already does. Looking back through this thread, I'm guessing the slowness with `xargs` that you experienced is because the original answer used `xargs -n 1` when it didn't really need to.

This is equivalent to your method one except that `xargs` automatically deals with the maximum command line length:

```
git tag | sorting_processing_etc | xargs git push --delete origin
```

`xargs` can run processes in parallel too. Method 2 with `xargs`:

```
git tag | sorting_processing_etc | xargs -P 5 -n 100 git push --delete origin
```

The above uses a maximum of 5 processes to handle a maximum of 100 arguments in each process. You can experiment with the arguments to find what works best for your needs.

Comment: Interesting. You learn something new about a Unix command everyday. I'll need to test my use case with this alternative.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a tag created starting with the **#** character, e.g. `#ST002`, you might find that u are unable to delete using normal patterns. i.e.

```
git tag -d #STOO2
```

Will not delete the tag, but wrapping it in a **String Literal** like so

```
git tag -d "#ST002" or git tag -d '#ST002'
```

That will get it deleted. Hoping it will help someone who made the mistake of using **#** to write tag names.

Answer (score 4):

To delete a tag on your remote repository, you can use

```
git push <remote> :refs/tags/<tagname>
```

The way to interpret the above is to read it as the null value, the value before the colon is being pushed to remote tag name.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to share an alias I created which does the same thing:

Add the following to your `~/.gitconfig`

```
[alias]
    delete-tag = "!f() { \
            echo 'deleting tag' $1 'from remote/origin ausing command: git push --delete origin tagName;'; \
            git push --delete origin $1; \
            echo 'deleting tag' $1 'from local using command: git tag -d tagName;'; \
            git tag -d $1; \
        }; f"
```

The usage looks like:

```
-->git delete-tag v1.0-DeleteMe
deleting tag v1.0-DeleteMe from remote/origin ausing command: git push --delete origin tagName;
To https://github.com/jsticha/pafs
 - [deleted]             v1.0-DeleteMe
deleting tag v1.0-DeleteMe from local using command: git tag -d tagName;
Deleted tag 'v1.0-DeleteMe' (was 300d3ef22)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a local testcase to test it locally without messing with a remote:

```
~/p $ mkdir gittest    
~/p/git $ cd gittest/
~/p/gittest $ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/local_user/p/gittest/.git/
 ~/p/gittest $ touch testfile.txt
 ~/p/gittest $ git add testfile.txt
 ~/p/gittest $ git commit -m "initial commit"
[master (root-commit) 912ce0e] initial commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 testfile.txt
 ~/p/gittest $ git tag
 ~/p/gittest $ git tag -a testtag
 ~/p/gittest $ git tag
testtag
 ~/p/gittest $ git show-ref
912ce0e40635c90241fdab756dce7ea34938de57 refs/heads/master
b0a6c15cabb990e6d6c46f762891b63608d962f3 refs/tags/testtag
 ~/p/gittest $ cd ..
 ~/p $ mkdir gitbare
 ~/p $ cd gitbare
 ~/p/gitbare $ git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/local_user/p/gitbare/
 ~/p/gitbare $ cd ..
 ~/p $ cd gittest/
 ~/p/gittest $ git remote add origin /Users/local_user/p/gitbare
 ~/p/gittest $ git push -u origin master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 215 bytes | 215.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /Users/local_user/p/gitbare
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
 ~/p/gittest $ git push origin testtag
Counting objects: 1, done.
Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 163 bytes | 163.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To /Users/local_user/p/gitbare
 * [new tag]         testtag -> testtag
 ~/p/gittest $ git show-ref
912ce0e40635c90241fdab756dce7ea34938de57 refs/heads/master
912ce0e40635c90241fdab756dce7ea34938de57 refs/remotes/origin/master
b0a6c15cabb990e6d6c46f762891b63608d962f3 refs/tags/testtag
 ~/p/gittest $ git push -d origin testtag
To /Users/local_user/p/gitbare
 - [deleted]         testtag
 ~/p/gittest    git tag -d testtag
Deleted tag 'testtag' (was b0a6c15)
 ~/p/gittest $ git show-ref
912ce0e40635c90241fdab756dce7ea34938de57 refs/heads/master
912ce0e40635c90241fdab756dce7ea34938de57 refs/remotes/origin/master
 ~/p/gittest
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of good answers here already, but if you ever need to delete all the tags, this one liner using PowerShell can be used:

`foreach($tag in (git tag)) { git tag -d $tag.Trim(); git push origin :refs/tags/$tag }`

Here, we get the list of all tags, delete each local tag followed by deleting the remote tag (tested on GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest way for me, personally:

First delete locally:
`git tag --delete <tagname>`

Then delete on the remote:
`git push --delete origin <tagname>`

Answer (score -2):

To delete a Git tag that's already been pushed, you'll need to follow a few steps. First, ensure you have the necessary permissions to delete the tag from the remote repository since it affects shared history.

Locally delete the tag: Use the command **git tag -d**  to delete the tag from your local repository. For example, **git tag -d mytag.**

Push the deletion: Now, you need to push this deletion to the remote repository. Use **'git push origin :refs/tags/'.** For instance, **'git push origin :refs/tags/mytag'.**

This command pushes nothing (:) to the remote tag reference, effectively deleting it. However, please note that this won't remove the tag from other contributors' local copies if they've already fetched the tag. They'll need to perform similar steps to update their local repositories.

And hey, while working with Git, exploring different commands and understanding how they interact with the repository can be really helpful. It's like unlocking a whole cluster of functionalities that make version control smoother!

Comment: Duplicate: This has been explained in other high scoring answers.

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me

```
git push --force origin refs/tags/<tag_name>:refs/tags/<tag_name>
```