# How do you remove a tag from a remote repository

Tags: git, git-tag

Is it possible to untag a revision that has been push upstream using git.

This is what has happened:

```
git tag 1.1
git push --tags origin master
```

Doh! That was meant to be version 1.1beta

Can you rebase and repush upstream. No other member of my team has pulled from origin yet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete a remote git tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-remote-git-tag)

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You can delete a remote tag the same way that you [delete a remote branch](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/508913253/deleting-branches-on-a-remote).

```
git push origin :1.1
```

And delete your local tag with:

```
git tag -d 1.1
```

Comment: I did: git tag -d 1.1 && git push origin :1.1 and that did the trick. Many thanks.

Comment: Because remember, a branch IS a tag, just one that moves its HEAD along with the lastest commit that belongs to it. Internally, they're exactly the same.

Comment: Actually - a lightweight tag is just like a branch. An annotated tag is an actual object, like a commit, that has a reference point to it.

Comment: As of git version 2.7.4, if I try to delete the tag locally after the remote delete, I get error: tag '0.0.60' not found. I suppose it gets automatically deleted

Comment: In case you need to delete _many_, _many_ tags, I figured out two ways to do this at least several magnitudes faster. The fastest is to include multiple `:tag` arguments to `git push`. The second uses the Github API to delete remote refs (tags) directly. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/43421561/657764)

Answer (score 26):

```
git push --delete origin TAGNAME
```

Of course, you still have to delete the tag locally by running:

```
git tag -d TAGNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can give the following command once you are in the local repository path (using cmd,code editor,IDE).

```
git push origin :your_tag_name_to_be_deleted
```