# git tag delete and re-add

Tags: git, github, git-tag

On git hub I re-added the tag by doing:

```
git tag -d 12.15
git push origin :refs/tags/12.15
git tag -a 12.15 -m '12.15'
git push --tags
```

The tag is still referring to the old tag on github, but locally it is done right.

UPDATE: It seems github is listing the last commit wrong, but downloading it correctly.

Comment: `git tag -d` deletes a tag. Actually what i came here looking for... :)

Answer (score 90):

The reference is https://stackoverflow.com/a/5480292/1317035

You just need to push an 'empty' reference to the remote tag name:

```
git push origin :tagname
```

Or, more expressively, use the `--delete` option:

```
git push --delete origin tagname
```

Pushing a branch, tag, or other ref to a remote repository involves specifying "push where, what source, what destination?"

```
git push where-to-push source-ref:destination-ref
```

A real world example where you push your master branch to the origin's master branch is:

```
git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

Which because of default paths, can be shortened to:

```
git push origin master:master
```

Tags work the same way:

```
git push refs/tags/release-1.0:refs/tags/release-1.0
```

By omitting the source ref (the part before the colon), you push 'nothing' to the destination, deleting the ref on the remote end.