# How can I move a tag on a git branch to a different commit?

Tags: git, git-tag

I created a tag on the master branch called `v0.1` like this:

```
git tag -a v0.1
```

But then I realized there were still some changes I needed to merge into master for release 0.1, so I did that. But now my `v0.1` tag is stuck on (to invoke the post-it note analogy) the wrong commit. I want it to be stuck on the most recent commit on master, but instead it is stuck on the second most recent commit on master.

How can I move it to the most recent commit on master?

Answer (score 1590, accepted):

Use the `-f` option to [`git tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag):

```
-f
--force

    Replace an existing tag with the given name (instead of failing)
```

You probably want to use `-f` in conjunction with `-a` to force-create an annotated tag instead of a non-annotated one.

### Example

1. Delete the tag on any remote before you push

   ```
   git push origin :refs/tags/<tagname>
   ```
2. Replace the tag to reference the most recent commit

   ```
   git tag -fa <tagname>
   ```
3. Push the tag to the remote origin

   ```
   git push origin --tags
   ```

Comment: This only works if you haven't pushed the code off your machine.  If you have, the best answer is 'there's plenty of numbers in the world' as it's probably not worth the hassle.

Comment: If you had already pushed your tag you can still update the remote tag with a forced push `git push -f origin <tagname>`

Comment: You don’t have to use forced push, if the tag reference can be fast forwarded to the new place.

Comment: What is not mentioned here and in the docs is, that this indeed does move the tag message, if no new message is given.

Comment: Note that in #3 `git push origin master --tags` is going to push tags, _and the `master` branch if you have committed any changes to it locally_. Just use `git push origin --tags` if all you want to do is push tags.

Comment: `git tag -fa <tagname>` worked perfectly, it moved the tag and opened up the existing message in my text editor, just had to exit to keep it.  You can then push the tag with `git push <tagname> -f` to force it to update on the server.  Looking at the remote tags on github with `git ls-remote` I do see duplicates of all the tags with `^{}` appended, those actually point to the commit with the tag, It's something with annotated tags because that is always there and the actual tag ref without those characters points to an object with the tag message and commit information, not the commit hash.

Comment: @eedeep it seems those `^{}` are always there for annotated tags, they actually reference the commit hash, where the ref without those is to the annotation.  Try `git show <hash>` on both those hashes, the straight tag name hash has the tag information (tagger, date, comment) above the commit information.

Comment: @BenHocking actually you could simplified the statement `git push origin :refs/tags/<tagname>` to `git push origin :<tagname>`

Comment: What does the 1st step do? How is `git push origin :refs/tags/<tagname>` deleting anything? Doesn't it just push the tag to the origin?

Comment: @DanM.: The important part is that there is nothing before the colon. See [How to delete a remote tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-remote-tag) for more details.

Comment: @GregHewgill ok, thanks. I didn't quite get why extra deletion step might be necessary. Why simply force pushing is not enough?

Comment: @DanM.: I'm not quite sure, I didn't write that part of the answer (it was added by somebody else, incorporating information from some of the previous comments above).

Comment: Good to know: on GitLab users with Developer role have permission to add Tags, but not remove them — you need to be Owner or Maintainer.

Comment: Is `master` required in `git push origin master --tags`? I just use `git push origin --tags`.

Comment: What happens to the repositories of those who have already pulled those tags? Do they get duplicate tags or git handles the initial tag removal automatically?

Comment: I think the answer should include advice "avoid moving tags just like you avoid force pushes!"  For existing repos that already have the tag at the old commit, a simple 'git pull' does not move the tag to the new commit. In a panic I deleted the tag locally and re-pulled, which moved the tag. But there must be a better way?

Comment: Yes, Git does not really provide good mechanisms for moving tags.

Comment: I feel `git push origin --delete <tag name>` is much more intuitive than the `:refs/...` approach.

Comment: @User1291: That's right, the `push --delete` option was added in [Git 1.7.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.0.txt) in February 2010. At the time this answer was written, using the `:refs/...` syntax was guaranteed to work on a given git installation, particularly if it was slightly older.

Comment: As @c32hedge and @ian-jamieson pointed out, including `master` in the push just seems like an error.  I'm going to edit the answer to remove it.

Answer (score 409):

To sum up if your remote is called `origin` and you're working on `master` branch:

```sh
git tag -d <tagname>                  # delete the old tag locally
git push origin :refs/tags/<tagname>  # delete the old tag remotely
git tag <tagname> <commitId>          # make a new tag locally
git push origin <tagname>             # push the new local tag to the remote
```

Description:

- Line 1 removes the tag in local env.
- Line 2 removes the tag in remote env.
- Line 3 adds the tag to different commit
- Line 4 pushes the change to the remote

You can also change line 4 to `git push origin --tags` to push all of your local tag changes/updates to the remote repo.

The above answer is based on content in the question by @eedeep, as well as answers by [Stuart Golodetz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8044599/4561887), [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8044605/4561887), and @ben-hocking, and comments below their answers, and @NateS's original comments below my answer.

Comment: Line 4 works for pushing an explicit *single* updated tag to the remote repository, in case you don't want to update all tags, as I didn't.

Comment: Also, if you have a tag and a branch with the same name (e.g. `1.0.0`) it will error out with `error: src refspec 1.0.0 matches more than one`.  You can specify that you want to push a tag specifically by using `git push origin tags/1.0.0`

Answer (score 350):

More precisely, you have to force the addition of the tag, then push with option --tags and -f:

```
git tag -f -a <tagname>
git push -f --tags
```

Comment: This answer completed the accepted answer by including `-f` to push the tags.

Comment: If you don't want to add a comment, omit the `-a`.

Answer (score 105):

Delete it with `git tag -d <tagname>` and then recreate it on the correct commit.

Comment: @eedeep: I think Greg's response is actually better here to be fair.

Comment: Keep it simple.  Delete it, do what you did before again.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, for its simplicity. Also does not use -f force excessively.

Comment: @chinnychinchin. This is one place where use of force really is not excessive. It's no different than saying "accept mine" during a merge.

Answer (score 96):

I try to avoid a few things when using Git.

1. Using knowledge of the internals, e.g. refs/tags. I try to use solely the documented Git commands and avoid using things which require knowledge of the internal contents of the .git directory. (That is to say, I treat Git as a Git user and not a Git developer.)
2. The use of force when not required.
3. Overdoing things. (Pushing a branch and/or lots of tags, to get one tag where I want it.)

So here is my non-violent solution for changing a tag, both locally and remotely, without knowledge of the Git internals.

I use it when a software fix ultimately has a problem and needs to be updated/re-released.

```
git tag -d fix123                # delete the old local tag
git push github :fix123          # delete the old remote tag (use for each affected remote)
git tag fix123 790a621265        # create a new local tag
git push github fix123           # push new tag to remote    (use for each affected remote)
```

`github` is a sample remote name, `fix123` is a sample tag name, and `790a621265` a sample commit.

Comment: I think OPs tag was annotaged. The third line could be like this instead

    `git tag -a fix123 790a621265         # create a new local, annotaged tag`

Comment: I hate that this is the best answer. I wonder why it has to be so complicated? Tags are well suited for marking which commit is for production, so I need to change which commit it's tacked to quite often. Using a branch which you just rebase all the time is currently easier, but it's redundant when the environment is of no concern to your repository contents (something worth striving for).

Comment: @Zyl: Why use tags for tracking production HEAD? Branches are even better suited for that. Use a branch and fast-forward it most of the time when production upgrades. In case of regressions you can hard-reset the branch.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer That's what we ended up doing in most repos, but I can't tell you the amount of devs who do not understand that merging A into B does not guarantee equality of state. Communication and knowledge transfer are way glanced over in the industry, but they affect how we do things more than anything.

Answer (score 59):

I'll leave here just another form of this command that suited my needs.
There was a tag `v0.0.1.2` that I wanted to move.

```
$ git tag -f v0.0.1.2 63eff6a

Updated tag 'v0.0.1.2' (was 8078562)
```

And then:

```
$ git push --tags --force
```

Comment: This did the trick and is the simplest answer. Thank you!

Comment: FYI: yhis does lose any message that was associated with the tag

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke good to know! Too busy to test right now but I wonder if it can be fixed just by using `-fa` instead of `-f`.

Comment: @Nakilon I've tried it with th `-fa` option, but unfortunately it returns with an error: too many arguments.

Answer (score 17):

Alias to move one tag to a different commit.

In your sample, to move commit with hash e2ea1639 do: `git tagm v0.1 e2ea1639`.

For pushed tags, use `git tagmp v0.1 e2ea1639`.

Both alias keeps you original date and message. If you use `git tag -d` you lost your original message.

Save them on your `.gitconfig` file

```
# Return date of tag. (To use in another alias)
tag-date = "!git show $1 | awk '{ if ($1 == \"Date:\") { print substr($0, index($0,$3)) }}' | tail -2 | head -1 #"

# Show tag message
tag-message = "!git show $1 | awk -v capture=0 '{ if(capture) message=message\"\\n\"$0}; BEGIN {message=\"\"}; { if ($1 == \"Date:\" && length(message)==0 ) {capture=1}; if ($1 == \"commit\" ) {capture=0}  }; END { print message }' | sed '$ d' | cat -s #"

### Move tag. Use: git tagm <tagname> <newcommit> 
tagm = "!GIT_TAG_MESSAGE=$(git tag-message $1) && GIT_COMMITTER_DATE=$(git tag-date $1) && git tag-message $1 && git tag -d $1 && git tag -a $1 $2 -m \"$GIT_TAG_MESSAGE\" #"

### Move pushed tag. Use: git tagmp <tagname> <newcommit> 
tagmp = "!git tagm $1 $2 && git push --delete origin $1 && git push origin $1 #"
```

Answer (score 14):

One other way:

Move tag in remote repo.(Replace HEAD with any other if needed.)

```
$ git push --force origin HEAD:refs/tags/v0.0.1.2
```

Fetch changes back.

```
$ git fetch --tags
```

Comment: This is more "transactional" than the other answers.

Answer (score 14):

Remove locally:

```
git tag -d v0.1
```

Remove on remote:

```
git push origin --delete v0.1
```

Then re-add locally and push v0.1 to the most recent commit:

```
git tag -a v0.1
git push origin --tags
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use github and want change commit for release (for example you find that don't commit smth after creating release).You can use

```
git push origin :refs/tags/<tagname>
```

After this command github delete your tag and your release will become a draft. It means you can recreate release and select commit. Your files and your message will be saved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move an annotated tag, changing only the targeted commit but preserving the annotation message and other metadata use:

```sh
moveTag() {
  local tagName=$1
  # Support passing branch/tag names (not just full commit hashes)
  local newTarget=$(git rev-parse $2^{commit})

  git cat-file -p refs/tags/$tagName | 
    sed "1 s/^object .*$/object $newTarget/g" | 
    git hash-object -w --stdin -t tag | 
    xargs -I {} git update-ref refs/tags/$tagName {}
}
```

usage: moveTag <tag-to-move> <target>

The above function was developed by referencing [teerapap/git-move-annotated-tag.sh](https://gist.github.com/teerapap/22bcb6ab836aed64676c).

Comment: It seems this is no longer needed: `git tag -f -a my_tag` already preserves the message of a previous message (with git version 2.11.0).

Answer (score 1):

If the desired end result is updating the contents of a tag already on remote:

1. `git checkout <tag_name>`
2. Commit your changes
3. `git tag -f <tag_name>`
4. `git push -f origin <tag_name>`

Answer (score 0):

If needed to update all tags to the latest commit of the current branch:

```bash
for i in $(git tag); do
  git push origin ":refs/tags/$i"
  git tag -fa $i
done
git push origin --tags
```