# How do I merge a git tag onto a branch

Tags: git-merge, git-tag

I'm trying to find the syntax for merging a tagged commit onto another branch.  I guess it's straightforward but my feeble search attempts aren't finding it.

Answer (score 403, accepted):

You mean this?

```
git checkout destination_branch
git merge tag_name
```

Comment: Same here so I git fetch --tags origin then I could: git merge tagname

Comment: Is there a way to merge all tags at once?

Comment: Is it possible the other way? Merge a branch to the tag? I tried "git checkout tag_name" and "git merge branch". But ended up checking out the branch instead of merging.

Comment: @learner a Tag identifies a specific commit. You can't merge into a specific commit so you'd need to move the tag to the commit you want. This would address the how on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044583/how-can-i-move-a-tag-on-a-git-branch-to-a-different-commit

Comment: Ensure that tags are pushed after they are created so that they are available at the origin (remote)'s branch,  and therefore others can get them:
git push origin <tagname>

If you missed pushing tags in the past, push all using:
git push origin --tags

To fetch/pull tags:
git fetch[pull] --tag

Comment: This worked for me. But only the problem is, git does not show any inform after tag merge. I expected it will be showing the changes in chageslist. It is not showing. I am using Android studio with in git integrated. Any advice to see the change list ??

Comment: This should be like the first answer (I mean in top lol). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 113):

Remember before you merge you need to update the tag, it's quite different from branches (`git pull origin tag_name` won't update your local tags). Thus, you need the following command:

```
git fetch --tags origin
```

Then you can perform `git merge tag_name` to merge the tag onto a branch.

Comment: I had to do `git remote add upstream git@github.com/org/repo` followed by `git fetch --tags upstream` to make it work.

Answer (score 8):

Just complementing the answer.

Merging **the last tag** on a branch:

```
git checkout my-branch
git merge $(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
```

Inspired by https://gist.github.com/rponte/fdc0724dd984088606b0

Answer (score 3):

With modern versions merge will autodetect the tags as follows

```
git checkout <my-branch>
git merge tags/<my-tag>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the only comprehensive and reliable way I've found to do this.

Assume you want to merge "tag_1.0" into "mybranch".

```
    $git checkout tag_1.0 (will create a headless branch)
    $git branch -D tagbranch (make sure this branch doesn't already exist locally)
    $git checkout -b tagbranch
    $git merge -s ours mybranch
    $git commit -am "updated mybranch with tag_1.0"
    $git checkout mybranch
    $git merge tagbranch
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the game here, but another approach could be:

1) create a branch from the tag (`$ git checkout -b [new branch name] [tag name]`)

2) create a pull-request to merge with your new branch into the destination branch

Comment: This will just create unnecessary branches.

Comment: it depends @Anuja 'cause you can delete the source branch after the merge via tool or via command line