# Add a commit to a release that was created before the commit

Tags: git, github

I've just created a new release for my repo on GitHub (https://github.com/Lrnk/self-esteem-snake/releases) and almost immediately afterwards realised that I'd forgotten to commit a change that I wanted to be in this release. I have now committed that change.

Is there any way to add commits to releases/tags after they've been released? Or is my best bet making a new release with the changes included?

Comment: This is what minor / patch versions are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, tags can be moved; see [this other answer: How can I move a tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8044605/711380). However this is confusing for everyone so you should probably just make another release instead...