# Replace remote tag with Git

Tags: git, tags, branch

I have some tags on my "origin" repository. Then I realized I needed to add some changes on one of the tags, and push them back on my repository.
Is there a way I can push an existing tag to the repository in one time, or should I delete the tag before ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I move a tag on a git branch to a different commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044583/how-can-i-move-a-tag-on-a-git-branch-to-a-different-commit)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

So if you need to move a tag (eg: **"v0.5"**) on a git branch (eg: **"master"**) to a different commit, probably a newer one, then you can use the `-f` option to [`git tag`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-tag.html):

```
-f
--force

Replace an existing tag with the given name (instead of failing)
```

You probably want to use `-f` in conjunction with `-a` to force-create an annotated tag instead of a non-annotated one.

### Example

1. Delete the tag on any remote before you push

   ```
   git push origin :refs/tags/<tagname>
   ```

   or for our example:

   ```
   $ git push origin master :refs/tags/v0.5
   To git@github.com:org_name/repo_name.git
   - [deleted]         v0.5
   ```
2. Replace the tag to reference the most recent commit (using -f will save as the `git tag -d <tagname>` local tag deletion step).

   ```
   git tag -fa <tagname>
   ```

   or for our example:

   ```
   $ git tag -fa "v0.5" -m "version 0.5"
   Updated tag 'v0.5' (was f55c93f)
   ```
3. Push the tag to the remote origin

   ```
   git push origin --tags
   ```

   or for our example:

   ```
   $ git push origin master --tags
   Counting objects: 1, done.
   Writing objects: 100% (1/1), 196 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
   Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
   To git@github.com:org_name/repo_name.git
   * [new tag]         v0.5 -> v0.5
   ```

Comment: the -f options cause the following error for me:  error: ```failed to push some refs to 'gitserver....'```

Answer (score 89):

This should not be the practice, though you can delete the tag and push the change to the remote repo.

```
git tag -d tag1
git push origin :refs/tags/tag1
```

Comment: Also `git push --delete origin tag1`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5480292/5637701)

Comment: In 2023 (v2.37.1), that didn't work for me without `--follow-tags`: `git push --follow-tags origin :refs/tags/stage`.

Comment: Why shouldn't this be a practice?

Answer (score 12):

Assuming `newtag` is the new tag and `oldtag` is the old tag. Simply do:

```
# Create new tag that points to the same of old tag
git tag newtag oldtag

# Remove oldtag
git tag -d oldtag

# Remove oldtag in remote machine
git push --delete origin oldtag

# Propapate newtag to remote machine
git push --tags
```

Comment: With this solution, the comment in annotated tag is the old one. If ypu want to replace to another, you have to delete the old tag (`git tag -d oldtag`, `git push --delete origin oldtag`) and make new tag (`git tag -a newtag HASH`, `git push --tags`)

Answer (score 9):

Way simpler way to replace a tag, also on remote:

```
git tag -f mytagname
git push -f --tags
```

Comment: Other working trees may still have the old tag ref, even after pulling

Comment: This is good as a one step solution when you're in total control of the remote as an alternative to delete the remote reference then add back the same reference. Because github releases break if the ref is removed remotely

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but it sounds like it would be simplest to delete the tag, push your change, then re-add the tag...