# How can I edit tag on gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

I tagged my repository on gitlab. Then I updated my repository. Now I want to tag with same number to current repository.

Example;
master ---> 1.0.0
branch (I updated master)
master (merged with branch)
Now I want to tag 1.0.0 this master

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace remote tag with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20076233/replace-remote-tag-with-git)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly create a tag through GitLab Web pages.
You might try create it through a [GitLab API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/tags.html#create-a-new-tag), but since you want to force replace an *existing* tag, that would fail as well.

That is why you have to [update said existing tag locally first, and force push it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55250897/6309).