# Change connected commit on release github

Tags: git, github, release

How you I change the connected commit on a github release?
[image: Release]

I want to change it to an earlier commit, because I created the release afterwards (after some commits to release 0.9)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

When you consider the GitHub API [for creating a release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release), you see a release needs:

- a tag
- a commit referenced by that tag

So you need to [move your tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21127037/6309) (locally first, then push it to your GitHub repo)

```
git tag -f -a <tagname> [<commit> | <object>]
# or, to avoid an editor
git tag -m "tag message" -f -a <tagname> [<commit> | <object>]

git push -f <remotename> refs/tags/<tagname>
```

for Example:

```bash
git tag -m "moving tag to new commit" -f -a my_tag [commit hash]
git push -f origin refs/tags/my_tag
```

Then see if that is enough for the release to be updated.
(See "[How do you push a tag to a remote repository using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63156836/6309)")

If not, you might have to delete that release, and recreate it on the same tag (which will refer to the new commit)

---

After doing this, if you get an error `would clobber existing tag`, then you need to sync local tags with remote using `git fetch --tags -f` and the push new commits.

Comment: I did the first line before posting here, but it did not work. The second line fixed it :)

Comment: how do you specify the commit id in the first command? My commit id is: `10a4ff2`. So what should my command be? `git tag -f -a v1.2.0 ...???...`

Comment: @ParthTamane Simply `git tag -f -a v1.2.0 10a4ff2`, as illustrated in https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#_tagging_later

Comment: @Sam Sure, I have edited the answer accordingly. You can also edit it directly: I will review and approve your edit.

Comment: Note that once you run `git tag -f -a <tagname> <commit_Hash>`, you'll be prompted to enter a messgae in a texteditor. You need to type a mesage and save the file to proceed. Without the message you'll get `fatal: no tag message?` error

Comment: @Gangula Running with -m (`git tag -m "tag message" -f -a <tagname> [<commit> | <object>]`) should be enough to avoid the editor part.

Comment: after doing this I got an error when I try to push a new commit - `would clobber existing tag`. So before pushing any new commits I had to fetch tags from remote using `git fetch --tags -f`. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58438257/6908282

Comment: @Gangula Good point. Thank you for the edit!