# How to get rid of "would clobber existing tag"

Tags: git

I'm using git in VSCodium and each time I try to pull git is complaining.

Looking into the log I see

```
> git pull --tags origin master
From https://github.com/MY/REPO
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 ! [rejected]        latest     -> latest  (would clobber existing tag)
   9428765..935da94  master     -> origin/master
```

Doing the command with `--force` helps until the next time.

It's unclear to me what's going wrong here. What happened and how can I resolve this issue?

I mean: Besides trashing my local repo and cloning again.

Comment: Most common reason is that someone "moved" a tag by deleting it and recreating somewhere else (e.g. a version tag is outdated because of a fix) - and pushed it

Comment: for me this conflict happen all the time, I suspect the azure devops pipeline causes it so ignoring is currently a good solution

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Since you say it's unclear what's going wrong, I assume you're not using that tag for anything and you just want to do your own work.

Turn off this setting:

[image]

*Or add this `"git.pullTags": false` in the settings.json file`*

Now you're all set.

---

**Detailed explanation:**

Tags are just references to specific commits (just like branch names). The main difference is that `git` (as far as I know) assumes tags will not change, where branches are expected to be updated.

So, the "error" is that you have in your local a tag called `latest` pointing to commit X - but the remote has a tag called `latest` pointing to commit Y. If you apply the change from the remote you will overwrite your local tag.

VSCode will pull all tags by default, thus you get the error.

There isn't anything *wrong* with having a "moving" tag like `latest`, that just isn't something VSCode takes into account (personal opinion).

---

Alternatively, you can avoid the issue by using the command line and manually entering the `git pull` command. Specifically, you need to omit `--tags` to skip this step of the process.

If you do this, your tags will not be updated - but I don't think is a concern here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had to update my VSCodium, but then it worked.

I think, I could also get rid of my local tag?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: I think this answer is better because it will solve the problem permanently, not just a one-time fix. Especially useful if your team is re-tagging regularly.

Comment: Even I used the described solution, I also found that the solution described in the article https://stackoverflow.com/a/5373319/2724543 helps to solve the error.

Comment: for those why cannot see the image, it's 
Git: Pull Tags
[  ] git fetch all tags while pulling
in vscode settings

Comment: Thanks!!! Ever since we started using a build process that runs on our server (creating a "moving" tag for those build brances), the VS Code `git sync` hasn't been working. It's not *that* big a deal to just switch to the command line and `git push`, but it was an annoying point of friction 

Comment: While Tuan's answer has the most votes, I like this one very much as it explains the underlying process very vell.

Comment: In my opinion not a good option. Consider not to use re-tagging. I would go with `git fetch --tags -f` as mentioned in another answer here.

Answer (score 1327):

You should update your local tags with remote tags:

```
git fetch --tags --force
```

Then pull again.

**Reason**

On remote, someone deletes a tag and creates a new one with the same name, then this will happen on your local

Comment: This worked for me. I was having issues with VSCode then running this in command line fixed the issue. :)

Comment: Thanks, can you explain more about this please? Is this a one time command, what exactly was the issue and how does this solved it..

Comment: @Sagivb.g on remote, someone deletes a tag and create a new one with the same name, then this will happen on your local

Comment: yes - this happened to me since we recently added CI to keep replacing the `latest` tag

Comment: If you're working with a fork, be sure to use`git fetch --all --tags --force`.

Comment: Given that `git pull` performs a fetch followed by a merge, why do you suggest `git fetch --tags --force` followed by a pull, rather than `git pull --tags --force`? (Assuming user is happy to have the merge performed automatically by `pull`)

Comment: @MikeA experience taught me that if you are assuming something while coding, unless it is obvious, don't do it.

Comment: It was a genuine question @Hunter, I'm interested in why you would do it that way.  Let me phrase it differently: if you are happy to have the merge performed automatically by pull, why would you `git fetch --tags --force` followed by a pull, rather than `git pull --tags --force`?

Comment: @MikeA it's a personal reference. I prefer to fetch the tags/commit before pull, rather than pull directly and let git do a merge. I like to merge the code myself, because in the past, git did auto merge and mess up the code for me. No sarcasm intended.
So, to answer this question, I don't assume that people will be happy with auto merge. Therefore, I gave the minimal solution that could solve the problem with no side effect, no hidden operations, etc.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  Turns out when we converted our remote origin from Bitbucket to Github, all tags were essentially "re-created" by Github and thus all old tags I had locally "would be clobbered" and the normal fetch --all --tags --prune rejects.  Hope someone else is helped by this info.

Answer (score 49):

The reason may be that you or other contributors deleted an original tag and recreated the same tag.

The solution:

```
git fetch --tags -f
```

Forced to refresh the local tag

---

When using the  button to update the code in the editor, the default will first use `git pull --tags origin master`

Therefore, you can add this `"git.pullTags": false` in the configuration file settings.json of the Vscode

Answer (score 15):

Edit: To be clear, the original question was related to a `git` issue. While it may not be obvious, `yarn` can also have git dependencies. So for the 0.1% of users that has this error while running `yarn install`, this is for you! If not, just use the accepted/top answers.

---

I got this error for a package while trying to run `yarn install`. The accepted answer was for the current repo and didn't work for me, but this worked:

```
rm -rf **/node_modules && yarn cache clean
```

I'd tried just removing `node_modules` before, guess cleaning yarn cache was what did it.

Comment: what is yarn and is it related to git?

Comment: `yarn` is a package manager, often used as an alternative to `npm`. Rather than using a package, you can add a git dependency to install from a git repo instead. I assume reseting the yarn cache allows it to update the git tags properly, similar to how the accepted answer suggests to fetch the tags.

Comment: I wish this wasn't downvoted that much. I get that the original question was strictly for git, but a google search for my yarn error gave me this question as the top result, and this answer was exactly what I needed.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed but I didn't see it initially since it was downvoted so much. Thank you @eckc !

Comment: It's a good answer and worked for me, however the dangerous thing is `**/`. The right thing is to delete only the node modules from the repo you are getting the error. That is: `rm -rf ./node_modules && yarn cache clean`

Answer (score 6):

If this is a regular occurrence where tags are deleted and recreated (for instance, the [recommendation for GitHub Actions](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/master/docs/action-versioning.md#versioning) is to have a floating major version tag, and "latest" could be something tagged with [actions-tagger](https://github.com/Actions-R-Us/actions-tagger)), you can edit your `.git/config` to add the following refspec:

```ini
[remote "origin"]                                                                                                                                              
  url = https://github.com/org/repo                                                                                                                 
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*                                                                                                                

  # extra refspec
  fetch = +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Since tags are not namespaced per remote, you should understand the impact this could have, but it may make sense for certain use cases.

To explain why this is necessary, see the [git-fetch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt) (emphasis mine):

> Until Git version 2.20, and unlike when pushing with git-push, any updates to `refs/tags/*` would be accepted without `+` in the refspec (or `--force`). When fetching, we promiscuously considered all tag updates from a remote to be forced fetches. **Since Git version 2.20, fetching to update `refs/tags/*` works the same way as when pushing. I.e. any updates will be rejected without `+` in the refspec (or `--force`).**

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/7G23I7Z

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
git fetch --tags
yarn cache clean
```

fixed the issue for me when the issue was coming from another symlinked library where I already fixed the issue.