# how to fix the would clobber existing tag problem

Tags: git, semaphore-ci

I've got myself into trouble with git tagging and now my build pipeline (semaphore) is broken with the following error message.  Not sure how to get this resolved.

**Error message**

```
Unpacking 
objects: 100% (32/32), done.
From github.com:jack/my-app
   c8a2420..75ea515  develop         -> origin/develop
   b4069ce..9f672e1  feature/RY-1144 -> origin/feature/RY-1144
   8dbf387..ac9db9d  master          -> origin/master
 ! [rejected]        v1.46.0         -> v1.46.0  (would clobber existing tag)
 * [new tag]         v1.47.0         -> v1.47.0
```

**Update**

I'm using visual code with some extensions and looking at the history of repo within visual code it looks like the tag can be deleted?  If I click on the 'x' next to the tag 'v1.46.0' and then commit and push (with follow follow-tags) will this resolve my problem?

[image: git history]

Comment: Did you move the `v1.46.0` tag to a new commit? If so then you probably need to ask your build pipeline to clear out any caches and start from a fresh clone of your repository.

Comment: I don't know in truth what happened.  Can the tag causing the problem just be deleted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of "would clobber existing tag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031165/how-to-get-rid-of-would-clobber-existing-tag)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The cause is : tag `v1.46.0` on your remote does not point at the same commit as tag `v1.46.0` on the local clone (local to your CI server).

---

a. Check that the `v1.46.0` tag points at the right commit on the remote server (update it manually if needed),

b. Force update the tag(s) on the CI server by running one of the following two commands :

```
# to force update all tags :
git fetch --tags --force

# to force update only this specific tag :
git fetch origin -f v1.46.0:refs/tags/v1.46.0
```

Comment: I assume the table is saying the left column is local and the right column is the remote

Comment: The output mentions the branch/tags that were updated on the remote side (left column), and the references that will be updated on the local side (right column).

Comment: are you saying I can run the second line (and only the second line) and it will repoint the tag (v1.46.0) to the same commit on both local and remote?

Comment: @Jack : yes (better late than never :) )

Answer (score 2):

In general you can use `git tag -l` to show your local git tag, then `git tag -d <tag_name>` to delete the error tag. 
In your particular case, you need to use `git tag -d  v1.46.` to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by running the following command to delete the offending tag on the remote

```
git push --delete origin v1.46.0
```

Comment: This resolved the issue @Tuan Tran - thanks