# vscode git sync keeps executing with wrong arguments

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a docker workspace with vscode version 1.64.2. I had some abrupt shutdown a couple of days ago and after that, my vscode doesn't sync for me anymore.

I'm working on `git version 2.20.1`. apt says it's the latest.

However I have absolutely no problem with git itself: both `git pull` and `git pull origin branch` (**which I expect vscode to call**) work fine.
The problem is that sync button keeps trying to execute `git pull remotes origin/branch`, which obviously fails, and I have no idea how to change this configuration. I tried re-enabling builtin git plugins and it didn't help.

Of course I still have my shell and I can type git pull manually into it. But this causes me quite an inconvenience and I want to fix it.

The error message is :

```
> git pull --tags remotes origin/branch
fatal: 'remotes' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

my `git config -l` gives:

```
remote.origin.url=<<MY GITHUB REPOSITORY>>
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

which seems totally fine to me referring to the git document.

Answer (score 0):

Check for remotes in your settings:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git config -l | grep -i remotes
```

And see if, for testing, [removing the "Pull Tags" option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58031333/6309) would help in your case.

Comment: But I already checked git config and found no problems. The document says that my `remote.origin.fetch` is fine so there must be a bug around VSCode which parses refs/$1/$2 when it's supposed to be refs/remotes/$1/$2.

Comment: @PaulSohn A bug is always possible, but I did not observe the same issue with my VSCode 1.64.2. The point of `git config -l | grep -i remotes` is to make sure `remotes` is not included in any other Git setting.