# Always pull the latest version of code from git using bower.json

Tags: javascript, git, bower

We have a library repository that creates a new branch each time a new release is published

We have a app that refers to above mentioned library using `bower.json`: `"lib": "git+https://example.com/path/to/library.git#<release>"`.

Each time a new library release appears, we have to explicitly point `bower.json` to the new release # as shown above.

Question:

Is there currently a mechanism (tag?) for example `git+https://example.com/path/to/library.git#latest` that can *convey* to `bower`, to automatically pick up latest release (branch) in this case, everytime an `npm update` or `npm install` is called ?

Comment: Do you need to specify anything here? Won't you get the latest when you just omit the #latest part?

Comment: @JohnSmith I thought the default meant `master`. However, I am not very sure...I'll check that. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnSmith in my case, it did pull an older version...not exactly `master`. Cleared bower cache and did a bower reinstall. bower log says `git+https://example.com/path/to/library.git#*` whereas in `bower.json` I have `git+https://example.com/path/to/library.git`

Answer (score 1):

You'll be creating tag `latest` and updating it at each release so that it points again to the latest commit.

Here is the workflow for passing from a v1.0.0 to v1.1.0

1) As usual you tag your version (with your own semantic)

`git tag v1.0.0`

2) You also specify that it's your latest version

`git tag latest`

3) push to remote

`git push --tags origin master`

4) Now you can point your bower to `git+https://example.com/path/to/library.git#latest`

Then do some work on your library ... Get ready to release a new version

5) Tag the new version and push to remote

```
git tag v1.1.0
git push --tags origin master
```

6) Remove the previous `latest` tag on remote

`git push origin :refs/tags/latest`

7) Replace it pointing to the new commit

`git tag -fa latest`

8) Finally push this new `latest` tag to remote

`git push origin master --tags`

**Finally** : Repeat from step 5 at each release.

Some sources : [How can I move a tag on a git branch to a different commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044583/how-can-i-move-a-tag-on-a-git-branch-to-a-different-commit?answertab=active#tab-top)