# After rebase and force push, I have a detached/dangling commit/tag

Tags: git

What happened:

- New branch off master: **"rollback-appcompat"**
- Work on it and put **a tag on the last** commit "1.8.1.13"
- worked on master, now I want to **rebase my new branch on master**
- **Rebased fine**, but couldn't push to remote
- According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8940299/331021), I could simply **force push**, so I did that.
- Now I'm in a funny situation where I have the branch before it was rebased still existing like this:

[image]

As you can see, the purple is "rollback-appcompat" before it was rebased. How do I **get rid of that**? **I think it wasn't removed because I had a tag on it, is that correct?**

Comment: Is this remote public? Because rewriting public history would be bad... like crossing the streams.

Comment: *[...] it wasn't removed because I had a tag on it, is that correct?* Correct. All the commits  that are reachable from this tag will be visible in your log. You could [move the tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044583/how-can-i-move-a-tag-on-a-git-branch-to-a-different-commit) to the corresponding commit in the rebased branch's ancestry... but moving public tags, like rewriting public history, is considered bad practice.