# Restore git history from split repositories

Tags: git, merge, git-rewrite-history

When our project started we where not to familiar with git, and at some point decided to re-start the repository. This meant that we imported all file into the new repository, losing all history.

Today I'd like to know if there would be a way to re-combine these 2 repositories.
Basically the history of a file in the "old-repo" should be added to the history of that file in "new-repo".

Does anyone have an idea how to get started with that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this pretty easily by fetching the commits from the old repository then using `git rebase` to replay the history of the new repository on top of the old one.

First, fetch the commits from the old repository.

```
git remote add old_repo <url-for-old-repo> # Add old repository as a remote
git fetch old_repo # Fetch commits from old repo
```

Next, find the commit in the old repository that matches the root commit of your new repository. You might find `git log` helpful for this purpose. You can verify that the contents of the commits match by running `git diff <commit in old repo> <commit in new repo>` and checking to make sure there is no output from that command. If there is output from that command, either keep looking until you find a commit in the old repository that doesn't produce that output, or make one (by checking out a similar commit in the old repository, making the necessary changes to the working directory, and committing).

Once you've found this commit, find the immediate *child* commit of the root commit in the new repository. This should be the first commit in the new repo that introduces *new* changes that aren't in the old repository. You will use this commit, along with the commit you found in the old repository earlier, in the following command.

Run:

```
git checkout master
git rebase --onto <commit from old repo> <commit from new repo> --preserve-merges
```

This should replay the commits from the new repository onto the old repo. Assuming the output of the earlier `git diff` was blank as I suggested, you should encounter no merge conflicts. Once the command completes, the `master` branch should include history from the old repository.

Since this procedure involved changing the history of the repository, you'll need to use the `--force` option next time you push the master branch to the remote repository.

If you have any other branches besides master, you will need to follow a similar procedure as the one above to move them over to the new repository:

```
git checkout branchname
git rebase --onto <base on new master branch> <first commit in branch> --preserve-merges
```

Tags probably should not be moved, as they are meant to be immutable. If you really want to move a tag to the new history, see [How can I move a tag on a git branch to a different commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8044583/1157054).

Comment: Hey, Thx for the great answer!