# Git label linked to old commit after relabel when using bamboo

Tags: python, git, bamboo

I'm having trouble checking out a commit using labels.

I had made a commit and labelled the commit `1.0`. I had to do some rebasing that ended changing some of the commits in my history which lead me needing to relabel the `1.0` tag on a new commit. When I manually checked out the label using `git checkout 1.0` the new commit is checked out and it works great. There is a scenario where checking out the label ends up pointing to the old commit... The scenario is when I use a python script to perform the git checkout and I have the script called from a Bamboo Atlassian Job.

Does anyone know what could be causing the history not to be updated? Note that the bamboo job cleans up it's environment every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that you have [not deleted/push back the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8044605/6309) that you just moved locally.

```
git push origin :refs/tags/<tagname>
git tag -fa <tagname>
git push origin master --tags
```

If pushed, the Bamboo job would be able to fetch then checkout the right commit for the `1.0` tag.

The [OP tyleax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7619353/tyleax) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244295/git-label-linked-to-old-commit-after-relabel-when-using-bamboo/58245407?noredirect=1#comment102919568_58245407):

> I needed to do one more step.
>
> **Bamboo remote agents cache the git repository information**. I had to delete the cache in `xml-data/build-dir/_git-repositories-cache` on the next checkout it was able to checkout the correct commit via label.
> Without deleting, it was still pointing to the old commit

Comment: Thanks! This helped me the most of the way. I needed to do one more step. Bamboo remote agents cache the git repository information. I had to delete the cache in `xml-data/build-dir/_git-repositories-cache` on the next checkout it was able to checkout the correct commit via label. Without deleting, it was still pointing to the old commit.

Comment: @tyleax Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.