# In Git how to reset tags to the origin?

Tags: git

### What I have

- I have rewritten history with git filter-branch as described [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-author-info).
- I have pushed all changes to the origin.
- I have retested other repositories with `git reset --hard origin`.

### The Problem

The Tags, that are not getting properly retested.

Example:

I have a tag called "20.012", hash: `6db19313f732a60a94b949e882bf57cceb44b629`.
This tag has this hash in the repository where I have used git filter-branch and in origin.
But where I have executed `git reset --hard origin` it has still the old hash `637a98f3b230f37e16dd59b6eb45bab6f40bebda`.

How do I properly update all tags?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move a tag on a git branch to a different commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044583/how-can-i-move-a-tag-on-a-git-branch-to-a-different-commit)

Comment: No, your link is just about chaning and pushing tags. I needed to pull the changes, but I figured it out. (See my answer)

Answer (score 1):

A simple

```sh
git pull --tags --force
```

did the trick.