# Assign the latest release in GitHub (not using git)

Tags: git, github, release

### Scenario

---

I have 3 releases of this repository in **GitHub**:

- https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/releases

( tags and maybe other required related info could be seen by following the url)

The latest release is the v1.2:

[image]

However, the first version is marked as "**Latest Release**":

[image]

Then if I use this url below, I get the earliest version of my releases:

- https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/releases/latest

### Question

---

I wonder if its possibly to set the release that I want it to be the latest release, via the GitHub web, with no complicated things.

### Research

---

When I said "with no complicated things" is because I read this post below on which they comment to use the git console, but really I don't want to depend on git console to be clonning my repository and messing with tags and etc just to set the green indicator of the damn **Latest Release**.

- [Swap "Latest release" on github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822586/swap-latest-release-on-github)

That makes me think whether really GitHub doesn't provide any "**Set this as the Latest Release**" friendly button on their web?, why they don't?, I hope just I'm missing something in their web because this is very annonying for their online users.

Comment: kudos for using [GitHub Dark](https://github.com/stylishthemes/github-dark) :) glad to see people using our project!

Comment: It appears to be handled automatically based on tag date so you can only change it through git. If you don't like the git CLI, you can use a git GUI app instead

Comment: @sircapsalot The theme makes anyone feels so familiar that I didn't remembered to deactivate it to give "real" images in my question, congratulations for the design!

Comment: @mzulch Thanks for comment, I use this GUI https://desktop.github.com/ but I'm not sure if it support this kind of task, if you know it please let me know. It also comes with portable git console but I would like to avoid using it as specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three of your tags — 1.0, 1.1, and 1.2 — are linked to [this commit](https://github.com/ElektroStudios/ElektroKit/commit/6fbce42a8c59b0a06f679a369d19b7a1282023d0). So in this case, all three releases are identical.

If you add or merge a new commit on the `master` branch that's tagged with 1.3, but don't update the last 3 tags, then this will become your latest release.

If you tag the commit correctly, `git tag --contains` should only output the latest tag. However:

```
$ git tag --contains
1.0
1.1
1.2
```

And as you can see, each tag points to the same commit:

```
$ git rev-list -1 1.0
6fbce42a8c59b0a06f679a369d19b7a1282023d0
$ git rev-list -1 1.1
6fbce42a8c59b0a06f679a369d19b7a1282023d0
$ git rev-list -1 1.2
6fbce42a8c59b0a06f679a369d19b7a1282023d0
```

TLDR: Make a new commit, then tag it, and don't update the other tags.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm thinking in the way to manage what you suggested to do but I'm not sure how it will affect on the way I do things, please let me know the answer to this little question: To do a new commit, I use this GUI to clone the repository https://desktop.github.com/ , then I do the modifications in the file structure (for example to add a new version folder), then I commit. Doing those steps will update all the three tags?.

Answer (score 2):

Along with all 3 tags being linked to a single commit, I would recommend not creating a new directory for each new release.  git will handle the versioning and tags, you do not need to do so using directory structure.

Also, i use [Source Tree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) to maintain git repos and tags.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder if its possibly to set the release that I want it to be the latest release, via the GitHub web, with no complicated things.

Yes. Yes, it is possible, since Oct. 2022:

> ### [Explicitly Set the Latest Release](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-21-explicitly-set-the-latest-release) (Oct. 2022)
>
> At GitHub, we strive to make it easier for developers to release the best version of their code to users.
> As a result, we've rolled out a new feature that allows you to explicitly set which release of your code is the latest.
>
> Previously, a repository's latest release was the one created on the most recent date.
> In the event that multiple releases had the same date, the semantic version number broke the tie.
>
> This new feature provides an explicit toggle to mark a release "latest" when you create it.
> This gives you more control over your code, and it works both in the web interface and through the API ([GraphQL](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#release), [REST](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/releases/releases#create-a-release)).
>
> [image: https://i0.wp.com/user-images.githubusercontent.com/533773/191272069-4a954c55-6d3b-494f-9db3-57e0d8f7f6b8.png?ssl=1 -- Screenshot of setting to make a release the latest]
>
> Read more about [releases](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/about-releases) in the GitHub documentation.
>
> We appreciate feedback on this and other topics in the [GitHub Community discussions](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions).