# git remove tags permanently affecting all that pull from the same repository

Tags: git

I am encountering a problem removing tags:

I do remove a tag locally [git tag -d TAGNAME] and remote [git push --delete origin TAGNAME] [on removing tags see [How to delete a git remote tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-remote-git-tag/5480292#5480292]).
Now if other team members do pull [git pull --tags], will not get the changes, meaning the deleted tag's still there on their local repository. When one eventually pushes [git push --tag] the formerly deleted tag will reappear in the tag list.

Anybody an hint?

Thanks very much

Comment: Did you try `git fetch -p` -p means prune?

Comment: Hi, yes we did try that. But the outcome was still the same: the tag's still there.

Comment: Looks like the _prune_ option doesn't do this anymore with more recent versions of Git. Check out the linked question from my comment above for some possible solutions.