# Tags won't get deleted

Tags: git

I'm my git repo I've `tag1`, `tag2` and `tag3` set by another user. I want to remove them from my computer.

I type `git tag -d tag1`, `git tag -d tag2` and `git tag -d tag3` in git bash.

So when I check the log they've disappeared but trying to push the tags using `git push origin --tag` it says everything is up to date but when pulling, I get the tags back.

I also want to add that I use `git push origin --tag` to push newly created tags and it works fine.

Why don't my tags get deleted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a remote tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-remote-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sure way to delete tags you've deleted locally on the remote is:

```
git push origin -f +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Comment: Says already up to date, and when doing 'git tag' git list all tags I just removed using 'git push --delete origin <tag name>'

Comment: Is this after you pull tags with `--prune`?

Comment: using `git push --tags --prune` I just reset all the tags I deleted

Comment: what text should I edit in that command or just enter it as it is?

Comment: I finally used `git push origin :refs/tags/[tagname]` with a combination of `git tag -d [tagname]` and it worked. Does your delete all tags at once?

Comment: @PresidentCamacho no editing is required, after you've deleted your tags locally using `git tag -d`, this is the exact command you can run to push *all* your tags from your local box to your remote box. So to answer your second question, yes, it deletes all tags at once.

Answer (score 2):

You need to push the deleted tags:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/<tag name>
git push origin :<tag name>
```

or:

```
git push --delete origin refs/tags/<tag name>
git push --delete origin <tag name>
```

Comment: Also, please note that `git push origin --tag/s` will not delete tags from the remote even if tags are deleted locally.

Comment: I used: 'git push --delete origin <tag name> it seems to delete the tag I created but the tags that were not created by me is still there even if git bash replied with that the tag got deleted.

Comment: run: `git fetch --all --prune`