# How to set tag for Maven release

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I'm using the [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) and I'm trying to tag every release with my Jenkins build number.

I've tried this from `pom.xml`:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <tagNameFormat>${env.BUILD_NUMBER}</tagNameFormat>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

And also from Jenkins when I'm calling Maven:

```
mvn release:prepare -tag=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}
```

However, I'm getting:

```
Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: tag 'my-project-1.3' already exists
```

I'm not sure what `1.3` stands for.

So how can I tag the release? I am doing any mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your pom is probably on version 1.3-SNAPSHOT

```
mvn release:prepare
```

Will update the version to 1.3, create the git tag "artifactid-version" in your case my-project-1.3, then set the version in your pom to 1.4-SNAPSHOT for the next iteration.

To fix your problem delete the tag see [How to delete a git remote tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-git-remote-tag)  then run mvn release:prepare again.

You may need to set your version back to 1.3-SNAPSHOT, this can be done with

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.3-SNAPSHOT
```

Or just edit you pom/poms.

Comment: If I do `mvn release:prepare` multiple times, the version still remains `1.3` and isn't incremented. Any idea why?

Comment: @octavian The version will be changed to 1.4-SNAPSHOT after the git  tag, so it that command fails this will not happen.

Comment: Can I do something like `mvn release:prepare -DnewVersion=${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`, where `BUILD_NUMBER` is the build number from Jenkins? I would like to specify a version depending on the Jenkins build number but I don't know how.

Comment: @octavian you are getting away from the idea of a "release" in maven terms.  A release is intended to be done rarely, say at the end of a sprint,  The version should be decided by the project.  Perhaps you don't really want to do a release?  Remember you still have all you git commits which you can go back to if needed.  HTH.

Comment: In the end, I will not do a release for every build. I will do a release only in some cases. However, I would like to have the build number in the name as well.

Comment: @octavian mvn:release:prepare will tag and update the version, mvn release:perform will install the released/tagged version in your repository (Nexus or similar).  This is then an immutable binary artifact which is linked to a source code state by the git tag.  Why do you need the build number?  You can return the the source with a simple "git checkout my-project-1.3"