# Cannot push to origin because of a tag that doesn't seem to exist

Tags: git, maven, jenkins

I have a Jenkins pipeline script. In it, I am calling [Maven's release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html) like this:

```
mvn release:prepare
```

This under the hood does a `git push` and I am getting this error:

```
Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] fatal: tag 'my-project-1.3' already exists
```

However, when I list the Git's local tags:

```
git tag -l
```

and tags from `origin`:

```
git ls-remote --tags
```

nothing is shown.

So how come I can't see this tag when listing the Git tags but the `push` fails because of it?

Comment: have you pushed the tags? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-git-remote-tag to check there is not a local one?

Comment: Probably I pushed them, in which case `git ls-remote --tags` should show them, right?

Comment: Also, I tried deleting it with `git push delete origin my-project-1.3` and it's not shown.

Comment: Does `git fetch --tags` and then pushing the tag help? Also did you try forcing the push?

Comment: `git fetch --tags` doesn't return anything new. `git push --force --delete origin job-management-1.3` returns the same `error: unable to delete my-project-1.3: remote ref does not exist`

Comment: 1. What is `job-management-1.3` in the above comment? 2. What I meant was to try something similar to `git push --force origin refs/tags/my-project-1.3:refs/tags/my-project-1.3` instead.

Comment: 1.I wrote that by accident. 2.`error: src refspec refs/tags/job-management-1.3 does not match any.`