# Remove all git tags expect a custom list of git tags?

Tags: git, bash, shell, version-control

Im trying to write a bash script that asks you for how many tags you want to keep and afterwards you can enter the tags you want to keep. Next the script should remove all remote git tags expect the ones entered before. But how can I achieve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git tag` to retrieve all tags in a repository

Then you will have to loop over these tags and if it does not match any of the given tags, [remove it using the following git command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-git-remote-tag) :

```
git push --delete origin tagname
```

Comment: How can I save the result of git tag?

Comment: `tags=$(git tag)`