# Delete tags fetched from one repository of many

Tags: git, tags, git-remote

I have a ported open source project and I want to update it on new version, so I added remote repository which contain necessary updates of project, but I've mistaken with link and add another one, execute `git fetch --all` so I fetch all commits and tags from remote repository to my local repo, after that add correct remote repo and fetched it, resolve merge conflict and push if with tags `git push --tags`, so I got tags from two repositories.

How can I delete tags from the first remote repository, which was wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I delete a remote tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-do-i-delete-a-remote-tag)

Comment: @IMSoP I suspect the question is more about how to list tags fetched from one of the two repositories.

Comment: @phd Yes, the question is how to delete tags whose were fetched from wrong repository. And do it easy, not by deleting all wrong tags one by one.

Comment: Well, there's two slightly different things there: the list of tags which were fetched (or pushed) at a particular time might be in a log somewhere, but I suspect not; on the other hand, you could get the list of tags which _currently_ exist on a particular repo, and compare them against another list. I'm not 100% clear from the question which two repos you'd want to compare though.

Comment: @AntonGolovenko Wild idea — delete all tags and re-fetch tags from the right repository. Start with backup, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a note: `git fetch --all` does not fetch all branches, nor all tags.  It fetches the same branches and/or tags it always would fetch.  What `--all` means here is *all remotes*.  That is, for each remote printed by `git remote` or `git remote -v`, it will run one `git fetch` to that remote.  So this has nothing to do with the actual problem, which is simply that you set up a remote-and-URL that you hadn't intended, and fetched from that one.

To delete some particular set of tags from *your* repository, use `git tag -d`.  This command allows you to specify more than one tag:

```
git tag -d tag1 tag2 tag3
```

will delete all three tags.

To ask some *other* repository to delete *its* tags, use `git push` with `--delete` or the refspec syntax that means "delete".  That is, suppose you want to ask `origin` to delete *its* tags `tag1`, `tag2`, and `tag3`.  Then you want:

```
git push --delete origin refs/tags/tag1 refs/tags/tag2 refs/tags/tag3
```

or:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/tag1 :refs/tags/tag2 :refs/tags/tag3
```

You *can* leave out the `refs/tags/` in each position, but this runs the risk of deleting a *branch* named `tag2`, for instance; using `refs/tags/tag2` makes it explicit that you would like `origin` to delete its *tag* `tag2`.

> @phd Yes, the question is how to delete tags whose were fetched from wrong repository. And do it easy, not by deleting all wrong tags one by one.

You still must delete each tag individually.  You can do that with one *command*, but that command has to list each tag to be deleted.

To get a list of tags you'd *like* deleted, consider asking the remote that had the unwanted tags for a list of its tags:

```
git ls-remote --tags <name-or-URL>
```

You'll probably want to redirect this output to a file.  Open the file in a text-file editor, remove all the lines that end with `^{}`, and remove the hash ID and initial `refs/tags/` parts that remain.  In vim, for instance:

```
vim /tmp/tags
:g/\^{}$/d
:%s,.*\trefs\/tags\/,,
```

will do the trick.  You now have a list of all the tags that are in that repository.

Note that blindly assuming that those tags *should* be deleted might be wrong!  Some of those tags may have already existed and still name the *correct* commits in your repository.  So you must now inspect these tags and make sure you really want to delete all of them.

Once you have the list, you can use `xargs` (if you have that), or your text editor again, to build the appropriate `git tag -d` and/or `git push --delete` arguments.  For instance:

```
sed 's,.*,git tag -d &,' < /tmp/tags
```

produces a full list of `git tag -d` commands; pipe this into the shell to make them execute:

```
sed 's,.*,git tag -d &,' < /tmp/tags | sh
```

Repeat with a substitute that builds a `git push --delete origin refs/tags/&` command from the tag name.  (When and whether to optimize this into a single `git push` is up to the user.)