# Delete tags from Bitbucket (Git) repository once and forever

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am having a hard time deleting some tags from Bitbucket. I created them during a testing phase with the assumption I could delete them, but I'm failing to do so.

Here's the steps I took to delete one:

1. Delete the tag using the web UI's tag button:
   [image: Delete via the UI]
2. Delete the tag locally from git:

   ```bash
   git tag -d TAG_NAME
   ```
3. Delete the tag in the remote repo:

   ```bash
   git push --delete origin refs/tags/TAG_NAME
   ```

However, when I do a git `pull` or `fetch`, the tag magically reappears in the repo.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which repo does it reappear? Local? Remote?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete a remote tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-can-i-delete-a-remote-tag)

Comment: @GaëlJ, presumably not, given that JBoy has done both `git tag -d` and `git push --delete`.

Comment: @GaëlJ it appears in both, i suppose first in the remote though, then with the ‘pull’ they are pulled into local

Comment: You'll have to show us logs of your git pull/fetch. And maybe also logs of your remove attempts.

Comment: I start to suspect that tags are actually in my colleagues local repos, and that they keep on pushing them every time they do a `git push`