# How to remove unneeded git commits?

Tags: git

I have some garbage commits in my git repositry. These have been created by e.g. the git gui when changing the latest commit again and accidently creating additional commits.

Now I have some commits lying around with no HEAD assigned (detached, not part of any branch).

As I want to tidy up, my question is: How can I delete these commits (see F, G and H)? Is this done using rebase or revert or reset? Or using another tool? On which commit do I have to sit to do it?

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E [master]
      \-- F -- G
           \-- H
```

Thanks

Christian

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listing and deleting Git commits that are under no branch (dangling?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
git reflog expire --expire=now
git gc --prune=now
```

Comment: That did not change anything. Sorry

Comment: @Christian Wolf: If that didn't change anything, then your commits F, G, and H are referred to by *something*. Perhaps you've got a tag pointing at them? Or a stash? We don't know.

Comment: @Christian: Have you verified using `git fsck --unreachable` that these commits are in fact dangling?  If not, then no amount of gc/prune will remove them.  You need to remove the reference(s) to them first.

Comment: I have to be been to tired yesterday. Today after sleeping and actualizing the commits do no more exist.

Comment: I was using gitk and thought I had the same issue, they weren't actually getting pruned. Try reload (shift-f5) vs update(f5).

Comment: I had to use the `--all` flag with `reflog` to prune my commits: `git reflog expire --expire=now --all`. Also, I found the `git fsck` command useful for finding out what was going on; specifically, `git fsck --unreachable --no-reflog` shows commits that are unreachable or only reachable from the reflog.

Comment: I had to use `git gc --prune=now --aggressive`

Answer (score 6):

Do the below:

```
git config gc.reflogexpireUnreachable now
git gc --prune=now
git config --unset gc.reflogexpireUnreachable
```

Comment: Thankx! – Your solution did remove 'recyclable commits', the accepted answer didn't.

Answer (score 3):

```
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

*Note: I know this is written in the comments of the most voted answer, but I keep finding myself coming back to this question and not immediately finding the answer that works.
The `--all` option is the only thing that is missing from the most voted answer, but is what makes it work for me.*