# Git: Delete one of two parent commits

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following commit history:

```
  A--B--C branch1
 /     /
I      D
 \
  \
   J branch2
```

and I want to simply delete commit D, which isn't connected elsewhere.

I tried `git rebase --onto B C`, but for some reason this deletes C as well and produces

```
  A--B branch1
 /     
I      
 \
  \
   J branch2
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975272/how-to-remove-unneeded-git-commits

Comment: @floverdevel D is a parent of C, but the linked question is about removing commits that are not within any branch, so if I'm not mistaken that won't help me

Comment: Can you merge squash D into C ? And then delete D.

Comment: @floverdevel do you have a suggestion how I could try doing that?

Comment: So `D` is a *root* commit? It's very odd to have a graph structure like that.

Comment: @torek D was created as a child of J, but then J was `reset HEAD~1`

Comment: Using `git reset` to change where the *branch name* `branch2` points does not change the parent linkage of `D`, so the graph drawing here is not right: `D` still connects right back to `J`. Fortunately that doesn't affect the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Save the hash ID of C somewhere.  The simplest method, other than using raw cut-and-pasted hash IDs, is to make a temporary branch or tag name, e.g.:

```
git branch save branch1
```

Then force the name `branch1` to point to commit `B`.  Assuming you are still on `branch1`—be sure you have nothing to commit too; use `git status` to check both of these:

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-B>
```

or similar.  If `branch1` still points to commit `C` you can use `HEAD~1` or `HEAD^1` to identify commit B, for instance.

Last, use `git cherry-pick` to make a *copy* of commit `C`, but in which this copy has only one parent.  To do so you must tell which of the two parents `git cherry-pick` should think of as `C`'s (single) parent for the purpose of this copying.  The parent to choose will be #1; this is almost always true anyway; and it's definitely true in this case, where `C` was made by merging `D`:

```
git cherry-pick -m 1 save
```

You can then delete the name `save` at any point (it was just around to remember the hash ID for commit `C`).

Note that you *could* cherry-pick `D` directly.  However, using `git cherry-pick -m 1 <thing-to-locate-commit-C>` means that if you had to resolve any conflicts when you did the merge, you don't have to re-resolve them now.

#### Long

Based on comments, the actual graph structure is this:

```
       A--B--C   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
      /     /
...--I     D
      \   /
       \ /
        J   <-- branch2
```

but this has no effect on the answer.

> I tried `git rebase --onto B C`, but for some reason this deletes C as well ...

It doesn't technically *delete* commit `C` at all; it just arranges for the name `branch1` to point to commit `B` (only).  That is, we can redraw the graph like this:

```
       A---B   <-- branch1 [after rebase]
      /     \
...--I       C   <-- branch1 [before rebase]
      \     /
       \   D
        \ /
         J   <-- branch2
```

The reason for this is that:

```
git rebase --onto B C
```

tells Git:

1. List all commits reachable from `HEAD` (using the name `HEAD` is in-built, part of `git rebase` itself) that are not reachable from `C` (from your argument `C`), minus some commits we can describe later.  List them in "reverse topological" order, i.e., older required commits before newer ones.

   In this case, the list is empty: there are no commits starting from `HEAD`—attached to `branch1` with `branch1` pointing to commit `C`—that are not reachable from commit `C` as well.
2. Set up a temporary branch pointing to `B` (from your argument `B`).
3. For all commits listed in step 1, copy those commits, building up this new temporary branch.
4. When done, change the name `branch1` to point to the final commit copied.

   Since no commits are copied, the temporary branch still points to `B`, so the name `branch1` is moved to point to `B`.

You could try to fix this by naming something other than `C` as "what not to copy".  The problem is that you only get *one* commit ID for "what not to copy".  You could specify `B`, but Git will then try to copy `D` *and* `J` (in the other order: `D` first, then `J`).  You could specify `D`, but then Git will try to copy `B`, `A`, and `I`!

The other remaining issue is that we noted above that in step 1, Git omits certain commits.  Specifically, it omits *all* merge commits—it won't try to copy `C` at all—and it also omits commits that are already in the upstream (through a mechanism I won't try to describe here; it doesn't apply in your case, so it's not important).  What this means is that even if you could somehow say "copy `C` but don't copy `B` or `D`", Git would toss `C` out of the list and *still* copy nothing at all.

This is why we need an alternative mechanism: a "by hand" rebase, using `git cherry-pick`.  We can cherry-pick `D` itself.  This means re-doing any conflict resolution.  Or, we can use `git cherry-pick -m 1 <specifier-for-C>` to cherry-pick the *effect* of merging `D` and doing any conflict resolution, and that's the method in the TL;DR section above.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the commit object `C` to remove parent `D`.

First run:

```
git log
```

to see commit-id's of C and D. Then run

```
git replace --edit <id-of-commit-object-C>
```

to edit parents of C. An editor will be shown. In the editor, remove the line  with `parent <id-of-commit-object-C>` and save.

After this you will have a replacement commit. To turn replacement commit into permanent, run:

```
git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: it was awsome also consider -f flag after filter-branch if you want do it with multiple commits