# Git: how to repack all loose commits

Tags: git, garbage-collection, git-gui, git-commit

After using `git gc` and `git repack` (with various options) I still have 4825 **loose commits** in the folder `.git/objects`. I would like to **have all of them in the pack file** with the rest or in another pack file.

I'm doing lots commit rewriting (amend + rebase) hence it's perfectly normal to have many unreachable commits. My .gitconfig contains these parameters to keep reflogs and unreachable commits for a long time.

```
[gc]
    reflogExpire = 300 days
    reflogExpireUnreachable = 200 days
    pruneExpire = 90 days
```

You may wonder if it make sense but I already needed and have recovered a few commits made several months ago. It happens we develop for many months on a new set of higher priority branches and afterwards continue on the older lower priority branches.

The main reason for this question is that `git gui` keeps on complaining to compress my database despites I have done this many times.
If we are not able to pack those loose commits then this "complaining" might be a bug in `git gui`.

Comment: wow, I had no idea people can actually work with that many loose commits

Comment: dupe / related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling

Answer (score 1):

Considering that [git bundle](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-bundle) is used to work with packaging objects only (calling [fetch-pack](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-fetch-pack)), did you try [to bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129214/backup-a-local-git-repository), and then clone your repo?

```
git bundle create aBundle --all # hopefully package everything, 
                                # the result being *one* file.
git clone aBundle newRepo       # recreate a full repo
# check if the cloned repo contains only packaged object
```

If this works, you might go on, using the new cloned repo as your main repo.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't help. I created such a bundle and it is 60 MB. However my file pack in .git/objects/pack is 64 MB and all the loose objects objects together take 32 MB. I tried to reference a dangling commit (of my repository) in the bundle but it didn't work (anybody knows how?).

Comment: @PaulPladijs: but does a clone of that bundle contains any unpacked object? I agree that a git bundle is likely to consider only referenced commit, though.

Answer (score 1):

The warning from git-gui is just a hint that you might want to do some maintenance. For most people having a high number of objects is just slowing them down. In your case, you should disable the warning. The function in question is `hint_gc` and it is called from near the end of the git-gui script file. Just comment it out as below.

```
if {[is_enabled multicommit]} {
        #after 1000 hint_gc
}
```

The multicommit business is a flag that determines if we are running as committool or a general purpose app.

If you want to use git-gui normally elsewhere, then you could add a respository specific flag instead. Something like:

```
if {[is_enabled multicommit] && ![is_config_true gui.skip_gc_warning]} {
        after 1000 hint_gc
}
```

should let you use `git config --bool gui.skip_gc_warning true` to disable that on a per-repository basis.

Comment: This is a good idea! I tried it but you have to remove the underscores `_` in `skip_gc_warning` to make it work. I'm still waiting for a repack solution (I'm curious if it's possible). Otherwise this may become the best answer.