# How to remove a commit

Tags: git, commit

[image]

I would like to delete the commit 9dfd73, the one highlighted.
As you can see it's not a branch. It's the result of a detached head.

I tried to make a branch on it and then delete that branch using git branch -D 9dfd73, but that deleted the branch, leaving the commit.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

For some reason, that commit doesn't exit in my tree any more, and I didn't have the chance to try your solution.

But I'll mark it as the correct answer if you can explain what does that command really does :-)

git rebase --onto <9dfd73>^ <9dfd73> HEAD

I understand it's something like: "take all the commits between the commit 9dfd73 and HEAD (excluding HEAD itself) and put them on top of the commit 9dfd73"

But I don't understand the ^ symbol.

Also, I'm not sure if the ID should be the same. Could you explain further?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the file > reload menu in gitk (<kbd>ctrl-F5</kbd>). This will probably make your commit disappear, since it is not the current commit anymore and it is not on any branch.

Comment: This is the correct answer to my specific problem. I need to dig into git  rebase --onto anyway, because that's a quicker way rather than creating a new branch and deleting it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command,

```
git rebase --onto <commit-id>^ <commit-id> HEAD
```

commit-id will be your SHA-1 id

Comment: Can't you rebase that commit and delete it?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on getting rid of it/them now, follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528593/1286639).  But, dont' worry about it; it will eventually disappear on their own.