# Remove an unreferenced commit from git repository

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-branch, git-rebase

I have a git commit history like this:

```
          U
         / 
A---B---C---D---E master
```

Nothing points to the commit `U`, but I know its hash. How can I completely remove this commit  from my repository as if it never existed? I'm the only person using this repo.

I tried using `git rebase`, but that can either delete parts of a branch or move commits, but doesn't seem to be able to delete a single commit.

If I do `git checkout <hash>` and then `git reset --hard HEAD~1` I don't see the the commit anymore. Is it actually gone completely or is it still hidden in the repo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually it will be cleaned up by git, but you can look into [git `gc`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) to actually force a garbage collect.

The `clean` command is different and won't take care of this for you.

Comment: What if I cloned the whole repo? Would unreferenced garbage objects be cloned as well?

Comment: @Jawap: no, they will not be cloned

Answer (score 19):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528593/2199657), simply use

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

`git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all` removes all references of unreachable commits in `reflog`.

`git gc --prune=now` removes the commits themselves.

**Attention**: Only using `git gc --prune=now` will not work since those commits are still referenced in the reflog. Therefore, clearing the reflog is mandatory.