# Scope of gc prune and git reflog expire, and related config

Tags: git, github, git-reflog

We are using throwaway integration branches which are pushed, and then later deleted and recreated. However the discarded branches are leaving dangling commits and trees which I can view with this command: `git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs`

I could clean them up with

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

or something similar, but I want to understand the scope of these commands and related configuration first.

So the specific questions:

- So that new clones are lean, how can I `gc` prune and clear the reflogs, not just locally but also on our remote repository hosted on GitHub?
- Can I set the related git config items (e.g. `gc.pruneexpire`, `gc.reflogexpire`, `gc.reflogexpireunreachable`) for the GitHub hosted repository?

P.S.: See here for useful context: [Listing and deleting Git commits that are under no branch (dangling?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling/16472069#16472069)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push to origin after reflog expire and gc prune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907313/push-to-origin-after-reflog-expire-and-gc-prune)