# git - Completely remove commits from an unrelated remote that was added accidentally

Tags: git

I have an interesting problem at hand. In a shared team repo, a team member added a remote to a completely unrelated repository (this was an accident).

e.g.

```
git remote add foreign-remote https://github.com/some-open-source-project
```

He checkout out the master branch of that repo and pushed it to our repo.

e.g.

```
git checkout foreign-remote/master
git checkout -b experiment
git push origin experiment
```

This created effectively two unrelated sub-graphs within the team repo:

[image: two sub-graphs]

The left part is our proper code, the right part is that foreign repository.

How can we completely remove that right part? It is not causing any harm but it is very annoying and I would like to get rid of this sub-graph, preferably without leaving any traces behind.

Also, is there a way of preventing this from happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the branches that points to the wrong graph from the remote. In your case it is `experiment`.

```
git push origin :experiment
```

If other developers already fetched that branch they must do a

```
git fetch --prune
```

**In more detail**

```
     A                         F
    /|\                        |
   B C D                       G
    \|/                        |
     E <-- origin/master       H <--- origin/experiment
```

Now if you remove the `experiment` branch from `origin` then commit `H` will not be referenced anymore. Thus the commits `F-G-H` will be deleted on a `git gc`.

After you removed it from the remote. The developers who already fetched it must do a `git fetch --prune` to remove the remotes that no longer exists.

*Make a backup clone if you want to feel safer*

> Also, is there a way of preventing this from happening?

Use gerrit code review. It let you define fine-grained access rights and you can reject a changeset on review. Thus the wrong commits would be discarded and not get integrated in your repository.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely pointed me to the correct direction. I deleted branches and tags. Then I had to see the reflog as well, I found some useful commands to verify that it works fine:

git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs will tell me about all the commits that are unreachable

git gc --prune=now will kill them

and running the fsck command again verifies that there's nothing left that is unreachable :-)

Comment: Found some useful information here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling