# "Git pull" on local branch then every files disappeared

Tags: git, github

I ran `git pull` on my local branch to pull new branch but with error:

```
warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.
```

Then I `checkout`'ed to new branch anyway but every files disappeared. I tried running `git prune`, `git gc` and deleting .git/.gc_log but no luck.

```
➜  gerege git:(nissan) git status
On branch nissan
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/nissan'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
➜  gerege git:(nissan) git pull               
Username for 'https://git.nmma.co': khangarid.d@nmma.co
Password for 'https://khangarid.d@nmma.co@git.nmma.co': 
remote: Counting objects: 73, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (71/71), done.
remote: Total 73 (delta 31), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (73/73), done.
From https://git.nmma.co/Gerege/gerege
   db33f62..2ec26ab  discovermongolia -> origin/discovermongolia
 * [new branch]      ecrc       -> origin/ecrc
   a286063..a05fbb9  master     -> origin/master
Auto packing the repository in background for optimum performance.
See "git help gc" for manual housekeeping.
error: The last gc run reported the following. Please correct the root cause
and remove .git/gc.log.
Automatic cleanup will not be performed until the file is removed.

warning: There are too many unreachable loose objects; run 'git prune' to remove them.

Already up-to-date.
➜  gerege git:(nissan) git checkout ecrc 
Branch ecrc set up to track remote branch ecrc from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'ecrc'
➜  gerege git:(ecrc) gco master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 7 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

Comment: You lost all your local files? Is it possible to provide git reflog command output?

Comment: Try `git fetch -p` then `git checkout -`

Comment: @LethalProgrammer git reflog seems to show nothing useful? I edited for my console log

Comment: @sajibkhan unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: @Hangai This may help you check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732141/whole-team-gets-too-many-unreachable-loose-objects-messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 7 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.

If your `local/master` have no important commits that you have not pushed yet then you can do **hard reset** your `local/master` with `origin/master`.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git reset --hard origin/master
```

---

> Is it possible delete EVERYTHING on local and pull a fresh new copy?

Say, you want to sync your local `feature` branch with your `origin/feature` branch. Then at first delete your current local `feature` branch then create a new `feature` branch with `origin/feature` history.

```
$ git checkout master
$ git branch -D feature                   # delete local 'feature' branch

$ git fetch                                
$ git checkout -b feature origin/feature  # create new feature = origin/feature
```

Note: Replace `feature` with the name of local branch

Comment: Master branch has some of its files now. But others still don't have anything in it but .gitignore. Is it possible delete EVERYTHING on local and pull a fresh new copy?

Comment: You can delete your local branch (say, `feature`) then create a new local `feature` branch with the history of `origin/feature`. Updated answer.