# delete a particular commit log in git/stash

Tags: git, github, git-stash

There was a file with credentials checked into `git/stash` accidentally. I've deleted the file in git stash. However, the commit log with the link to the deleted file still remains in the commit history. I tried to delete a particular commit log in `git/stash` following https://www.clock.co.uk/insight/deleting-a-git-commit but doesn't work. Any ideas what's the best way to resolve my issue? Thanks!!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "git stash". Do you mean the `git stash save` command, or do you mean Atlassian Stash which is built on top of Git?

Comment: try running `git gc` and then check again. It should remove the dangling reference.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing and deleting Git commits that are under no branch (dangling?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling)