# How to get rid of a commit?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

The following worked to update author/email, etc. However, it left a detached commit(the red in the image) that is the original initial commit. How can I get rid of it?

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter \
'\
export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME=userid;\
export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=useremail;\
export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=userid;\
export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=useremail;\
git commit-tree "$@"'
```

[image]

Comment: If this is the latest commit that you have done than you can use **git reset HEAD**

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari No. It had a list of commits. After changing all of the author/email. The original initial commit became isolated.

Comment: Is that awsering your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling ?

Comment: What do you mean, "get rid of"? As soon as it's unreachable, it'll be eligible for garbage collection. By having it checked out, you're *making* it reachable (since `HEAD` is a reference in and of itself), but check out something else (and maybe clear the reflog if you're in a hurry to be rid of it immediately) and that'll no longer be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way how to get what I expected. In `SourceTree`, go to `Repository` --> `Repository Settings ...` --> `Remotes` --> `Remote repository paths` --> removed all of entries under `Remote repository paths`. The bad thing is I have to add remote URL/Path once more.