# Delete unmerged git branche from history

Tags: git

To temporarily test differences in node modules between me and my team mate I created a branch and committed the `node_modules` folder. Since there was not an issue we never merged the branch, but it is still in the history, increasing the git size from 1Mb to 70Mb...

How can I permanently remove the branch with the commit from git history? It is already pushed to our gitlab remote.

Comment: Just delete the branch, and the contents will eventually (two weeks, I believe) disappear via Git's garbage collection. See [git gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc).

Comment: `git push origin :branch_name` will delete the branch.

Comment: Double check that the commits are unreachable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling