# How to remove my local branch history without affecting the master

Tags: git, github

I created a branch from the master, and have been adding and deleting a large number of binaries into the branch, As a result, the repo size has bloated to thrice its original size. I have removed the binaries and deleted the branch but the repo size does not change. How can i minimize the repo size?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc - but use caution!

Comment: The repo size may not change much because those binary files are still present in the history of the branch(es).  You have to go back and remove those binary files somehow.  The duplicate link offers one option.

Comment: @Console That's not what this question is about.  `git-gc` won't work in the case of binary files which are still being referred to by active commits, in active branches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen he deleted the branch therefore no active commits reference the binaries (as I understood the question).

Comment: @Console You might be right, but that would mean that this branch never interacted with anything else.  I have removed the duplicate mark, but it might have been appropriate.

Comment: @Console I need to be 100% sure whatever cleanup I do does not affect master or any other branch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete a Branch in git only the named ref is removed, the commits which store the source are still around and can viewed with `git reflog` or restored (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git)). Therefore deleting a branch does not free any diskspace (out of a view kb's). This commits are called *dangling commits* because there is no branch / tag that references the objects. To make git clean up this stuff call

```
git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

This does of course only work if you have no branch referencing the commits containing the binary. And this does aswell destroy the reflog - making it impossible to restore currently deleted commits and branches.

Take a look at this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528593/2250672

Comment: This is mostly right (& upvoted), except: *This objects are called loose objects because there is no branch / tag that references the objects.* That's not why they're called "loose". :-) Loose just means "not yet packed". In modern Git you don't need to care about loose vs packed, just run `git gc` as you show here. Meanwhile: `git reflog expire --expire-unreachable=now --all` - the only reflog you need to expire-unreachable from is that of `HEAD`, so you can trim this down a bit, but your caveat is correct, it's removing your safety belts.

Comment: @torek I may have mixed dangling and loose - I changed the wording to `dangling commits`.