# git: remove an unused branch and its commits

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I created a branch/tree with commits in a git repo a while ago that I will never use. How can I permanently remove that from my repo? This is all local - no remote repos or other users

before:

```
--A-----------D---E---F---G  <- master/head
   \---B---C                 <- will never use
```

what I'd like:

```
--A---D---E---F---G  <- master/head
```

Mercurial has a strip command that does what I need and hoped git has something similar

Comment: Do nothing. It will be garbage-collected eventually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listing and deleting Git commits that are under no branch (dangling?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling)

Comment: If there is no branch referring to commit `C`, you will not see `B` and `C` anymore, even if they technically still exist.

Comment: I ran git gc but B and C still exist

Comment: Thanks all. Still learning git but now in the right direction on this. And found I use a log alias with "--all" which is part of my problem. Can I close this or does a Mod close questions?

Answer (score 1):

I first move to another branch, not the one I want to delete, and then execute:

`git branch -D branch_name`

To delete a local branch. The -D is an alias for --delete --force, which deletes the branch 'irrespective' of its merged status.

Comment: I tried that. the branch name got deleted, but the commits were still there

Answer (score -1):

1. Checkout master branch

   ```
   git checkout master
   ```
2. Delete local branch

   ```
   git branch -d local_branch_name
   ```

   *Note*: `-D` is the same as `-d --force`

---

Additionally, to get remote repo updates for `master`:

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: **Don't** use `git pull` unless you know exactly what you will get. `git pull` does `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. It is wiser to run `git fetch` and inspect the result then run either `git merge` or, even better `git rebase`.