# Git: Remove broken stash

Tags: git, git-stash

I've got a broken stash:

```
% git stash drop            
fatal: log for refs/stash is empty
% cat .git/logs/refs/stash
%
```

It does show up in `git log --all`, though:

```
% lal

*   f32cdce - (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) (44 minutes ago) <Williams, Ken>
|\  
| * 05cc7d3 - (3 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
| * 6d9c8ae - (3 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
| | * 3fb311d - (refs/stash) (3 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
| |/| 
| | * 19be16e - (3 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
| |/  
| * ffea5e2 - (i2) (9 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
```

(`lal` is my alias for `git log --graph --pretty=format:'%h -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %Cgreen(%ad) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --all`.)

I did a `git stash apply 3fb311d`, so I've got the content of the stash secured.  Now, **how can I remove** that `refs/stash` from the tree so it doesn't keep complaining?

**EDIT**

Even after deleting the `refs/stash` reference as suggested by @mark-adelsberger, the commits show up in the history listing:

```
% lal

*   f32cdce - (HEAD -> develop, origin/develop) (31 hours ago) <Williams, Ken>
|\  
| * 05cc7d3 - (3 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
| * 6d9c8ae - (3 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
| | * 3fb311d - (3 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
| |/| 
| | * 19be16e - (3 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
| |/  
| * ffea5e2 - (i2) (9 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
| * 199af47 - (9 weeks ago) <Ken Williams>
...
```

This is using Git 2.29.0 (homebrew) on OS X 10.15.7.

Comment: `rm .git/refs/stash` ?

Comment: @matt I don't have a `.git/refs/stash` file.  I'm not sure where the stash info is being stored.

Comment: I assume you also did `rm .git/logs/refs/stash` ? Together, those two commands blow away your stashes.

Comment: @matt that does not seem to be true, even after removing both those files (and `find .git | grep stash` returns nothing) the stash is visible in `git lg --all`.

Comment: The question is not what shows up in `git lg --all`. What you asked us to solve is that `git stash drop` barfs. If you do what I suggested and the barfing stops, my work here is done! :)

Comment: That's a bit curious, because even if the reflog for `refs/stash` is empty, the `refs/stash` ref itself should get deleted. And, [after you manually deleted it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64756516/git-remove-broken-stash#comment114497076_64757207) it should stop showing up entirely. I wonder: do you have any added work-trees?

Comment: @torek nope, no work trees.

Answer (score 3):

*Update* - Added notes at end based on edited question

---

If `.git/refs/stash` is empty (or non-existant) yet git log shows a `refs/stash`, then I would suspect the `stash` ref got added to your `packed-refs` file somehow.

You can confirm the existence of the ref (regardless of its representation on disk) with

```
git for-each-ref refs/stash
```

and if this shows `refs/stash` (as I think it will), then you can delete the ref with

```
git update-ref -d refs/stash
```

As a reminder this is a potentially destructive command; in the specific case where you know you either have saved a ref to that data, or no longer want it, then it's fine.

---

So it's not clear to me what would cause log to report a commit that doesn't seem to be reachable (based on the graph and on the lack of refnames on that particular commit).  If I had a repo in that state I think I could figure out what's going on, but I really don't know how to reproduce the symptom.

My best suggestion is to do

```
git for-each-ref |grep 3fb311d
```

to see if for some reason a ref just isn't being named in the log.  IF that shows nothing, another idea is just

```
git for-each-ref
```

Or see if

```
git fsck
```

tells you anything useful.  If any of this turns up more information, I'll be happy to look at it and update with more suggestions.

Comment: Thanks Mark, `git for-each-ref refs/stash` does indeed give me a hash (starting with `3fb311d` so it's consistent with my log output).  I deleted it with `update-ref`, but it still shows (with no reference name) in my `git lg --all` output.  Why would that still show up, with no named references to it?

Comment: @KenWilliams Is the 3fb311d commit checked out at the time you generate the output?  If it isn't showing any named ref, and it doesn't have any children that lead to a named ref, and it isn't checked out, then I can't think of a reason it would be in the log output

Comment: Nope, `3fb311d` isn't checked out, it appears off to the side of the tree just like I showed in my original question, but now without the `refs/stash` name - I'll add an edit to the question to show that.

Comment: @KenWilliams - sounds like you have a repo in an unusual state.  I don't know how to reproduce it; added a few shot-in-the-dark ideas you could try, in order to gather more info

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it!  I did find a `refs/replace` reference by doing `git for-each-ref |grep 3fb311d`: `3fb311d7a9b1fb7d0d394ad723747b23d83f3ce9 commit refs/replace/da1018741f5cea52e4b139d8f0ca93f4d1c3d12c`.  Certainly didn't create that myself.

Comment: `git fsck` reports nothing interesting.

Comment: That looks like it came from `git replace`; see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace .  It is *very* odd to have a stash referenced in that way.

Comment: Yes indeed.  I've heard of `git replace` but never used it, certainly not in this repo.  The only slightly wonky thing I ever did in this repo was add a second remote, cherry-pick some commits from it, then remove that remote.

Comment: ACTUALLY, I do recall doing some `git filter-repo --path-rename foo:bar` stuff after cherry-picking, to get the content in the directory I wanted.  It looks like `filter-repo` might create some replace-refs, maybe that's related?

Comment: Could be.  I haven't worked much with `filter-repo` yet.  It's a little curious why it would perform any transformation at all on a stash, but depending on what commands were given maybe it didn't know better.  I wonder if the stash ref getting packed could also be related... but speculation aside, the question is - do you at this point know how to get your repo into an acceptable state, and is your question answered?

Comment: I've got myself into the same situation, but I've never used `git replace` or `filter-repo`, or added other remotes.

Comment: I finally found something that worked for me: `git fsck --full`