# How can I delete commits which not belong to any branch?

Tags: git, github

If I merge branch A into branch B and then delete A, which branch do commits from branch A (now deleted) belong to?
when I get the link of these commits, I found "This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository."

[image: check the screenshot here]

I tried all answers of this question and the didn't solve mu question
[Listing and deleting Git commits that are under no branch (dangling?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling)

What is the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Listing and deleting Git commits that are under no branch (dangling?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765234/listing-and-deleting-git-commits-that-are-under-no-branch-dangling)

Comment: I tried all the solution were mentioned there but they didn't solve my problem

Comment: it’s not clear which link you are referring to, after deleting branch a, when you get the link, and from where?

Comment: it will be better to add what you have tried and what was the output to the question, it will make it more clear

Comment: It's the link of the commit which i want to delete @GoDLighT

Comment: "merge branch A into branch B"; as a merge commit, or squashed or rebased?

Comment: Yes, as a merge commit @Joe

Comment: Are you trying to delete this commit because it has sensitive information (a secret or someone's personal information), or do you just want it gone?

Answer (score 7):

## TL;DR

You can't "delete" this commit.  *You* don't *have* this commit in the first place, and even if you did, you still wouldn't really be able to *delete* it.

## Long

> If I merge branch A into branch B and then delete A, which branch do commits from branch A (now deleted) belong to?

The answer you might want here—and it's not wrong, but it's not right either—is "branch B".  Unfortunately, there's a fundamental error in this question.  I believe this error itself comes from GitHub's rather misleading claim about a commit not "belong[ing] to any branch on this repository":

> ⚠️ This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.

The mistake in the question itself—and the reason the text above is misleading—is that commits do not owe their existence to the presence of branch names, in Git.  In Git, you can have as many commits as you like, and *no branch names at all*.  Commits never "belong to" *any* branch in the first place.

Instead, a key notion we use with Git is that of [*reachability*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reachability).  If some commit *C<sub>i</sub>* is *reachable from* some other commit *C<sub>j</sub> ,* in Git repository **R**, this means that *C<sub>i</sub>* is an *ancestor* of *C<sub>j</sub>* (or equivalently, *C<sub>i</sub>* ≺ *C<sub>i</sub>*, where "≺"—a sort of bendy less-than sign—is read as "precedes"): this defines a partial order on the commit graph, which is a [Directed Acyclic Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), or DAG.<sup>1</sup>

We then define *branch*—or at least *branch name*—in Git as *a reference (or ref) whose name begins with `refs/heads/` and whose hash ID is constrained to be that of a commit*, with *ref* itself defined as *a name containing a hash ID*.<sup>2</sup>  Hence a name like `refs/heads/branch` is a *branch* name, and the hash ID stored in this branch name must be that of some *commit*.

A commit *reaches* all its ancestors.  Each commit stores a list—usually just one entry long—of *previous commit hash IDs*.  These form commits into chains, with backwards-pointing arrows.  Simple cases have just one backwards arrow coming out of each commit, pointing to its predecessor:

```
A <-B <-C ... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here, in our simple repository **R**, we have exactly eight commits.  Instead of using Git's actual commit hash IDs, we've given them single uppercase letters.  (This scheme is impractical in a real repository: what would we do if there were more than 26 commits?  But it's useful for thinking about the issues here.)  The *last* commit we made, `H`, stores inside itself the hash ID of the second-to-last commit `G`.  We say that `H` *points to* `G`.  `G` stores `F`'s hash ID, so we say that `G` points to `F`.  This continues, backwards, down the entire chain of commits until we hit commit `A`.  Because it's the very *first* commit, it *can't* point backwards, and it doesn't: its list of parent hash IDs is empty.

---

<sup>1</sup>This particular definition is slightly backwards, because Git itself works backwards.  In a normal DAG, reachability would imply successorship, rather than predecessorship.  But in Git, all the arrows point backwards, instead of forwards.

<sup>2</sup>Most refs are spelled `refs/*`, but there exist *pseudo-refs*, such as `HEAD` and `CHERRY_PICK_HEAD` that do not.  Pseudo-refs are special cases that make things troublesome for the folks working on putting in a proper ref database for Git.  Note that pseudo-refs are per-work-tree, but some other refs, such as the bisection refs, are also per-work-tree.

---

#### Reachability from a branch name implies that a commit is on the branch

We start with our simple eight-commit repository ending with:

```
...--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
```

We've added the *branch name* `main` and stored in `main` the real hash ID of commit `H`.  So we say that `main` points to `H`, the same way that `H` points to `G`.  (For text / ASCII-art purposes on Stack Overflow I've failed to draw the arrow from `H` to `G` *as* an arrow: we just have to remember that commits only link *backwards*.  There's no link from `G` to `H`, only vice versa.)

This setup means that the name `main` allows us to reach any of the eight commits *in* the repository.  Let's now add two more branch names, `br1` and `br2`, both of which point to commit `H`:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1, br2, main (HEAD)
```

All three *names* point to commit `H`.  So all eight commits are *reachable* from *all names*.  This means that all commits are on all branches.

The `HEAD` attached to `main` here means that the branch name we're *using* is `HEAD`, and the current commit is therefore commit `H`.  Let's run `git checkout` or `git switch` now, to change which *name* `HEAD` is attached to:

```
git switch br1
```

This results in:

```
...--G--H   <-- br1 (HEAD), br2, main
```

The only thing that *changed* at this point is that `HEAD` is now attached to `br1`.  All eight commits are still there; we're still *using* commit `H`; but now we're using `H` *via* the name `br1`.

Now we make a *new* commit, in the usual way.  This new commit gets a new, unique hash ID, but we just call it "commit `I`" to keep our sanity.  To draw it in, we need to draw an arrow from `I` pointing back to `H`, and make the name `br1` point to `I`, because that's how Git actually handles this internally:

```
          I   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

We're now using commit `I`, through name `br1`.

If we add another new commit `J`, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2, main
```

We're now using commit `J` through name `br1`.  Now we switch to `br2`:

```
git switch br2

          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- br2 (HEAD), main
```

We're now using commit `H` again, through name `br2`.  If we make two *more* commits, we get:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H   <-- main
         \
          K--L   <-- br2 (HEAD)
```

*Et voila*, we have "branches"!  Commits `I-J` can be said to "belong to" branch `br1` and commit `K-L` can be said to "belong to" branch `br2`, but what about the commits up through `H`?  Some would say these "belong to" `main`, but Git makes no such distinction: they're "on" *all three branches*.  When we first made the two `br*` branch names, all the commits were "on" all three branches, and those commits still are on all three branches.  It's just that *new* commits `I-J` are *only* on `br1`, and *new* commits `K-L` are *only* on `br2`, at the moment.

When we use `git merge`, we're not really *merging branches*.  We're really *merging commits*.  Let's do that now:

```
git switch br1
git merge br2
```

The `git switch` makes commit `J` the *current commit*, by attaching `HEAD` to `br1`.  The `git merge` has Git locate not one, not two, but *three* commits:

- the current / `HEAD` commit, `J`;
- the commit we name on the command line: `br2` points to `L`; and
- the *merge base* commit.

The merge base is defined through the [Lowest Common Ancestor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lowest_common_ancestor#Extension_to_directed_acyclic_graphs) algorithm, whose inputs are commits `J` and `L`, and this algorithm coughs up the hash ID of commit `H`.

The merge itself works by *comparing the stored snapshots* in `H`, `J`, and `L`.  This allows Git to figure out "what we did" on the `H-I-J` chain, and "what they did" on the `H-K-L` chain.  (Note that commits `I` and `K` are used only for their *linkage* here, not for their snapshots: both link back to commit `H`, which caused commit `H` to be the merge base.)

If all goes well, Git makes the new merge commit on its own.  This new merge commit `M` has not one but *two* parents—two backwards-pointing arrows—linking to *both commits `J` and `L`, like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

I've temporarily taken all the *branch names* away from the drawing, because we don't need them: commits exist independently of any *branch names*.  But making a new commit in Git always does the same thing:

- when we made commit `I`, Git wrote the new commit's hash ID into the then-current branch name `br1`;
- when we made commit `J`, Git wrote the new commit's hash ID into the then-current branch name `br1`; and
- when we made commits `K` and `L`, Git wrote the new commit's hash ID into the then-current branch name `br2`;
- so now that we made `M`, Git writes `M`'s hash ID into the now-current branch name `br1`:

  ```
             I--J
            /    \
   ...--G--H      M   <-- br1 (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L
  ```

Names `main` and `br2` still exist, and still point to `H` and `L`.  There's no room to draw in `main`, in this ASCII art, and there's no *need* to draw in `br2` right now.  We can instead ask: *Which commits are reachable from the name `br1`?*  The answer is: *All of them!*

Commits `K-L` *were* only on `br2` before, but now, because of merge commit `M`, commits `K-L` are on *two* branches.  So that gets us an answer to your original question, as long as we **rephrase it slightly**: after a true merge, deleting a branch name is "safe" because the commits are still *findable* via the merge commit.  They're now "on" both branches, and taking away one name—the name we're not using right now, `br2` in this case—still leaves at least one other name that they're "on".

#### Caveat: not all merges are true merges

While the `git merge` command sometimes makes merge commits `M`:

```
          I--J   <-- br1
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

we can come up with other situations where it doesn't:

```
...--P--Q   <-- br3 (HEAD)
         \
          R   <-- br4
```

Here, `git merge br4` will do a *fast forward* operation instead of a merge, producing:

```
...--P--Q--R   <-- br3 (HEAD), br4
```

In the case of a fast-forward, deleting `br4` is still safe: the commit that used to be only "on" `br4`, commit `R`, is now "on" `br3` too.

But we can also run `git merge --squash`, and that particular option directs `git merge` to make a *non-merge* "squash" commit:

```
          I--J   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2

[we now run:
    git merge --squash br2
and a second Git command that we're forced to run, to get:]

          I--J--S   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

New commit `S` here, after the `git merge --squash`, has the same *snapshot* we'd get if we had `git merge` make a true merge.  That is, Git still went through all the normal "find the merge base, run two diffs, combine work" steps that it would do for a true merge.  But then `git merge` stops and makes us run `git commit`,<sup>3</sup> and when we do, `git commit` makes an ordinary non-merge commit, which I drew above as `S`.

---

<sup>3</sup>There's no good reason for this.  If we *want* this action, we can run `git merge --squash --no-commit`.  This combination is allowed!  It does the exact same thing as `git merge --squash` today.  But in the distant past, the `--squash` option was handled as a special case of `--no-commit`, so that it did both things, and that means that it now has to keep doing both things in the name of backwards compatibility.

---

#### Unfindable commits and garbage collection

In general, in Git, we—and even Git itself—*find* commits using names.  **They do not have to be branch names,** but they very typically *are* branch names, or in clones, remote-tracking names (`origin/*` for instance).  Regardless of the *kind* of name—branch name, tag name, remote-tracking name, internal bisection reference, or whatever it might be—the name holds *one* hash ID.  If that's a *commit* hash ID, it suffices to find all *predecessor* commits, through the graph reachability algorithms.

But sometimes we might have commits that can *only* be found by *one* ref, such as the one branch name `br2`:

```
          I--J--S   <-- br1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- br2
```

If we *delete* this one ref `br2`, how do we find commits `K-L`?

One answer is: *we don't*.  (Another—but only temporary—answer is to use Git's *reflogs*, which semi-secretly hold on to commit hash IDs for a while.   Eventually the reflog entries expire, though, and then we're back to the "we don't" answer.)

If we, and Git, *cannot* find a commit, that commit becomes eligible for "garbage collection" under `git gc`.<sup>4</sup>  Git will run `git gc` for you, automatically, at irregular and Git-determined times.  This `git gc` will—slowly and painfully, by crawling through the entire repository **R**—find any commits and other Git objects that *are* unreachable and, if several other conditions are met,<sup>5</sup> actually *remove* the objects from the repository objects database.

This gc system is quite clever.  It allows Git programs to generate internal objects freely whenever they're useful, then simply abandon them when they have no use any more.  The garbage collector / janitorial service will come along later and clean up.

---

<sup>4</sup>`git gc` is part of general Git maintenance-and-housekeeping, and there is ongoing work now on a `git maintenance` command that will handle this in a more generalized, predictable, and usable fashion for server setups.  It's possible that `git maintenance` may eventually be useful to ordinary users as well as Git administrators, but there is much more to be done here first.

<sup>5</sup>The most important one is that the object itself be sufficiently old.  Since `git gc` can be running "in the background" *at any time*, it's important that it not delete an object that exists because some command—say, `git commit`—has just *created* the object, just now, but not yet gotten around to hooking it up to be visible.  If `git gc` garbage-collected a fresh commit *just before* `git commit` could write its hash ID into a branch name, that would be bad.  So everything gets, by default, a two-week window to finish up whatever it's doing.  Two weeks is *probably* enough for `git commit` to finish writing out a new commit.

(Kidding aside, Git's operation is *so much faster* than the version control systems we used in the old days.  I'd best stop here, lest this turn into the [Monty Python Four Yorkshiremen sketch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ue7wM0QC5LE).)

---

#### So what is this claim from GitHub about, then?

When GitHub say:

> ⚠️ This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.

what do they mean?

The *direct* meaning is *this commit is not reachable from a branch name in this repository*.  Both the phrase I just quoted and my more-precise replacement phrase have two `this` adjectives, both functioning as determiners: a specific commit—presumably one you have displayed in a browser—and a specific repository by which their Git *found* the commit.

We just said that we usually find a commit using a name.  But in fact, we find the underlying commit *object*, in the repository's object database, using its hash ID.  The hash ID *is* the "true name" of the commit.  What we found using a name was the *hash ID*, not the commit object itself.  If we have the hash ID in hand, that's all we need—and when we look at a GitHub repository commit using a browser, we supply the commit hash ID.  For instance, the URL https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a73c6bdc717127c2da99f57bc630c4efd8aed02 ends with `5a73c6bdc7...`.  That's a commit hash ID.  So GitHub can access the commit *without* using a *branch name*.

Now, this particular commit—`5a73c6bdc7...`—is the most recent `master` commit, at the time I write this, so if GitHub look at the *branch names* in this repository, they immediately see that `5a73c6bdc7...` is the *tip commit* of `master`.  If, by the time you read this, the GitHub `refs/heads/master` name locates some *other* commit, it's easy for the GitHub software to see if `5a73c6bdc7...` is an ancestor of whatever the tip commit of `master` is *then*, and if so, `5a73c6bdc7...` is still *reachable from* `master`, and hence still "on" branch `master`.

If we pick some other commit in some other repository, though, perhaps *that* commit *isn't* reachable from any branch name.  If so, that satisfies the first part of the clause in the quote:

> ⚠️ This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository

and we could stop there, or speculate that perhaps `git gc` will eventually remove this commit.  (A `git gc` *won't* remove the commit if it's findable by some *other* name, such as a tag name.  You can have commits that can be found only via the tag name, not any branch name.  Whether GitHub will produce a warning like this for such commits is up to GitHub.)

But they go on to add this:

> and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.

This is GitHub-specific.  Forks are not part of Git: they're a GitHub add-on.  (This particular add-on is found on other hosting sites as well, but GitHub were there first, as far as I know.  Bitbucket and GitLab appear to modeled their forks on GitHub's.)

A fork, on GitHub, is a server-side clone with added features.  These added features include the ability to raise Pull Requests (which are another add-on feature from GitHub).  To make these Pull Requests work, GitHub internally make use of some tricks that Git has implemented for decades (at least since Git v1.0.0 in 2005-ish).  One of these tricks is that Git can look in *other repositories' object databases* to retrieve Git objects.  This means that if you have some repository **R<sub>you</sub>** on GitHub, someone else can have a different repository **R<sub>se</sub>** (`se` stands for Someone Else) that they forked from your **R<sub>you</sub>**.  They can make commits of their own and send them to **R<sub>se</sub>** ... and then, under whatever conditions might apply later, you can use a URL that embeds *their* commit hash ID under *your* repository's name and, due to this sort of alternates trick, see *their* commit, even though it's in *their fork*.<sup>7</sup>

The upshot of all of this is that you can view a commit that's in *their* repository, that they've raised as a Pull Request to *you*, as if it were in *your repository*.  When you do this, you will definitely trigger the same "does not belong to any branch on this repository" condition.  That will produce the warning you see here:

> ⚠️ This commit does not belong to any branch on this repository, and may belong to a fork outside of the repository.

In this particular case, the commit truly *is not in* your repository **R<sub>you</sub>** over on GitHub.  So there's no way to delete it *from* **R<sub>you</sub>**.  It isn't *in* **R<sub>you</sub>**, it's in **R<sub>se</sub>**.  You can just *see it from **R<sub>you</sub>***.

You can't tell, from the warning, which of underlying condition triggered the warning.  All you know is that the commit you are viewing now is not *reachable from* any of the *branch names* in **R<sub>you</sub>**.  That could be because it *is* reachable, but not from a branch name; it could be because it *isn't* reachable, and is waiting to be GC-ed; or it could be because it's in *someone else's* repository.

In all three cases, *you* can't delete the commit itself directly.  In one case, `git gc` might delete it on its own, but you can't make GitHub run `git gc`.<sup>8</sup>  In one case—if you have a tag for the commit, for instance—there may be something you can do that would then *enable* `git gc` to delete it on its own.  And in the final case, it's not yours to delete, even if you could get `git gc` to do it.

---

<sup>7</sup>The same sort of rules might apply to your commits as well: if they know the hash ID, they may be able to see those commits in *their fork*.  This has obvious security implications, and I don't know what GitHub may have done about these.  GitHub have a lot of very competent programmers and they may have made this all quite secure, so that you can only see their commits if they have raised a PR to you, and they can only see your commits if they're public.  I am merely pointing out that at the low level, careless use of "alternates" introduces various security issues, so be careful if *you* use this.

<sup>8</sup>*GitHub support* can run `git gc` *for you*, but you must contact them to get the process started.  In that sense, you *can* make them run `git gc`, but it's kind of indirect.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the identical issue on GitHub. My issue was that I discovered some remnants in my search after using `git filter-branch` to delete sensitive data from GitHub. But after I contacted GitHub support, the issue was resolved in 5 minutes.