git rebase (only to amend commits) involving two consecutive branches
I have a git repo with a linear local history of, let's say, 10 commits, where the first 5 is in branch1's history, and the last 5 commits is in branch2's history, and I want to fix the descriptions/author/date/other properties of these ten commits by amending them. The situation would be like this:
---(old history)---A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J
                               ^              ^
                               |              |
                            branch1       branch2

I'm not sure about how to proceed here. I can think of two strategies to do what I want to do, but I want to understand their potential effects first.

instead of doing a longer interactive rebase of 10 commits, I prefer to switch to branch1 first, do an interactive rebase over its last 5 commits, and when I'm done, switch to branch2 and do an interactive rebase of its last 5 commits. But since rebasing implies the creation of new commits in a "new branch", I don't know what would happen with the parent of the HEAD of branch1. The question is, will that strategy create some sort of weird state like this (let's call branch1' the new branch after the rebase):
---(old history)---?--?--?--?--?--F--G--H--I--J
                 |             ^              ^
                 |             |              |
                 |          branch1(???)    branch2(???)
                 |
                 |
                 --A--B--C--D--E
                               ^
                               |
                            branch1'

or will git fix the parent of F in the right way?

The other strategy is switching to branch2 and do an interactive rebase of its last 10 commits directly; but, again, the question is, where will the HEAD of branch1 point to then after the rebase? To a commit that is not in the branch2 history anymore?



It's not clear what end result you're expecting. Commits don't "belong to" branches. Rewriting the whole history from branch2 would leave branch1's HEAD pointing to a commit (E) that's no longer in branch2's history (now including E', the modified version), but you could then change what branch1 refers to.

@jonrsharpe Ok, I understand. But now, if doing a rebase (in normal, idea situations where there is no more branches involved), involves creating a new commits and removing the old ones, why isn't E removed after the rebase? Do git keep always track of the amount of existing references to a commit, and if that number reaches 0, then it removes it?

"involves creating a new commits and removing the old ones" - no, it doesn't involve removing the old ones. They're still there, in your repo, just no longer in the history of the current branch's HEAD. Look in your git reflog, for example. If it then becomes completely unreachable, it can get garbage collected at some point - https://stackoverflow.com/q/3765234/3001761.

It sounds like you want to first do the interactive rebase of branch1, then do a (non-interactive) rebase of branch2 to the new branch1 (it's still named branch1, but it now refers to E').  eg, your diagram is wrong.  You should have branch1 referring to E', with parent D', etc.  The ? in your diagram are still A, B, C, D, E. After you rebase branch2 to E', you can do an interactive rebase of branch2 to make the changes you want.

Your diagrams indicate a fundamental misunderstanding that should be cleared up.  If you start with:
---(old history)---A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J
                               ^              ^
                               |              |
                            branch1       branch2

and do an interactive rebase (eg git checkout branch1; git rebase -i A^), the commit diagram will look like:
---(old history)-*-A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--J
                 |                            ^
                 |                            |
                 |                        branch2
                 |
                 |
                 --A'--B'--C'--D'--E'
                                   ^
                                   |
                                branch1

Once you've done that, you can simply do:
git checkout branch2
git rebase branch1

and you will have:
... --A'--B'--C'--D'--E'--F'--G'--H'--I'--J'

with branch1 at E' and branch2 at J'.  Assuming your first interactive rebase really just changed commit metadata, there should be no merge conflics.  After this (or do it the first time), you can do git rebase -i branch1 (assuming you still have branch2 checked out) to get:
---(old history)---A'--B'--C'--D'--E'--F"--G"--H"--I"--J"
                                   ^                   ^
                                   |                   |
                                branch1             branch2

A key thing to remember is that commits are immutable.  When you do a rebase, new commits are created, but the old ones are not (immediately) deleted.  (They may get cleaned up in a garbage collection run at a later date, but unless you've changed some default settings that won't happen for a few weeks.)  Branches, however, are very mutable.  For example, every time you make a commit, the branch tip mutates to refer to the new commit.  The presence of branch1' in your diagram suggests that this point is not well  understood.

I'd recommend using --onto or at least --fork-point with the rebase of branch2. It's likely that A through E will fall out as you described, but it's not guaranteed. (Or maybe we should assume the second rebase is also with -i and it doesn't matter since A through E can be manually dropped.)
