How to delete a commit when both rebase -i and reset --hard don't work?
I have this tree:
git log --graph --all --oneline
* B1.1
* B1  
| * B2
|/ 
* A

I want to remove B2. I git switch B2 --detach and try both reset --hard or rebase -i, but none of them works:
git reset --hard HEAD^
git rebase -i HEAD^ (then drop B2) 

It seems that there is no more suggestion to try from Throw away local commits in Git and Remove old git commits.

What exactly do you mean "remove" it? Those commands are to move the head around, they never actually delete commits (just maybe make them unreachable). You should probably start by finding out which branch it's on, if you don't know already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1419623/3001761, and you actually want to delete that branch.

I mean to delete it like it has never existed

Because why? What's the context? At best you can do that locally by making it unreachable and forcing git to delete it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3765234/3001761. But if you've pushed it you can't make the remote delete it from the git CLI and it may be cloned to any number of other machines.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/78986624/3001761 suggests you're trying to remove a secret from GitHub, in which case everything you're doing here is pointless and you need to read https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

I've removed the troublesome tags since then, so it's just a problem of working with the tree now.

You cannot "delete a commit". It is the essence of Git that it keeps commits, fixed and immutable. If a commit is unreachable through the parent chain from any branch or tag, Git may eventually prune it; locally you can speed up that process but remotely you cannot. If the problem is very serious on a remote repo, your best bet is to delete the remote repo completely; if the problem is that a piece of secret info was included, and if that remote repo was public, you also need to consider that secret as now known to all the world.

think the best solution here is to use cherry-pick:
git checkout A
git checkout -b new-branch
git cherry-pick B1
git cherry-pick B1.1

after, push it

See the graph. This topology already exists. This is not what the question asked for.
